# How do I compare version numbers in Python?

Tags: python, version, string-comparison

I am walking a directory that contains eggs to add those eggs to the `sys.path`.  If there are two versions of the same .egg in the directory, I want to add only the latest one.

I have a regular expression `r"^(?P<eggName>\w+)-(?P<eggVersion>[\d\.]+)-.+\.egg$` to extract the name and version from the filename.  The problem is comparing the version number, which is a string like `2.3.1`.

Since I'm comparing strings, 2 sorts above 10, but that's not correct for versions.

```
>>> "2.3.1" > "10.1.1"
True
```

I could do some splitting, parsing, casting to int, etc., and I would eventually get a workaround.  But this is Python, [not Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701948/efficient-way-to-compare-version-strings-in-java).  Is there an elegant way to compare version strings?

Answer (score 690, accepted):

Use [`packaging.version.Version`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version.html#packaging.version.Version) which supports [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) style ordering of version strings.

```
>>> # pip install packaging
>>> from packaging.version import Version
>>> Version("2.3.1") < Version("10.1.2")
True
>>> Version("1.3.a4") < Version("10.1.2")
True
```

---

An ancient and [now deprecated](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0632/) method you might encounter is [`distutils.version`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.version), it's undocumented and conforms only to the superseded [PEP 386](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/);

```
>>> from distutils.version import LooseVersion, StrictVersion
>>> LooseVersion("2.3.1") < LooseVersion("10.1.2")
True
>>> StrictVersion("2.3.1") < StrictVersion("10.1.2")
True
>>> StrictVersion("1.3.a4")
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: invalid version number '1.3.a4'
```

As you can see it sees valid PEP 440 versions as “not strict” and therefore doesn’t match modern Python’s notion of what a valid version is.

As `distutils.version` is undocumented, [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/distutils/version.py) are the relevant docstrings.

Comment: Looks like NormalizedVersion will not be coming, as it was superseded, and LooseVersion and StrictVersion are therefore no longer deprecated.

Comment: It's a crying shame `distutils.version` is undocumented.

Comment: found it using search engine, and finding directly the `version.py` source code. Very nicely put!

Comment: @Taywee they better are, since they’re not PEP 440 compliant.

Comment: Mind that the implementation of LooseVersion can lead you to really weird exceptions if you pass to the constructor anything that evaluates to False. In particular, LooseVersion(None) and LooseVersion('') are accepted silently at construction time, only to raise obscure exceptions when you later want to compare them to another because the __init__ method did exactly nothing.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: module 'packaging' has no attribute 'version'` when I try to use the first method you mention. Using Python 3.7.3

Comment: To resolve error `AttributeError: module 'packaging' has no attribute 'version'` use this import statement instead `from packaging.version import Version, parse`

Comment: Note that in python 3 comparing distuilts.version.LooseVersion objects will sometimes produce a typeerror.

Comment: In Python 3.6+: `from pkg_resources import packaging` then `packaging.version.parse("0.1.1rc1") < packaging.version.parse("0.1.1rc2")`

Comment: This is pretty buggy! `version.parse('0.34~') < version.parse('0.33')` returns True

Comment: Super useful that you linked to the LooseVersion code!  Since it's undocumented, the docstrings were exactly what I needed to realize why I was having a bug (and convince me to upgrade!)... specifically that it doesn't support versions with 4 sections like 1.2.3.4

Comment: @gwelter's comment should be the top *answer* in this thread.

Answer (score 137):

The [packaging](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) library contains utilities for [working with versions](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version.html) and other packaging-related functionality. This implements [PEP 0440 -- Version Identification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) and is also able to parse versions that don't follow the PEP. It is used by pip, and other common Python tools to provide version parsing and comparison.

```
$ pip install packaging
```

```
from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
version = parse_version('1.0.3.dev')
```

This was split off from the original code in setuptools and pkg_resources to provide a more lightweight and faster package.

---

Before the packaging library existed, this functionality was (and can still be) found in pkg_resources, a package provided by setuptools. However, this is no longer preferred as setuptools is no longer guaranteed to be installed (other packaging tools exist), and pkg_resources ironically uses quite a lot of resources when imported. However, all the docs and discussion are still relevant.

From the [`parse_version()` docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#parsing-utilities):

> Parsed a project's version string as defined by PEP 440. The returned value will be an object that represents the version. These objects may be compared to each other and sorted. The sorting algorithm is as defined by PEP 440 with the addition that any version which is not a valid PEP 440 version will be considered less than any valid PEP 440 version and the invalid versions will continue sorting using the original algorithm.

The "original algorithm" referenced was defined in older versions of the docs, before PEP 440 existed.

> Semantically, the format is a rough cross between distutils' `StrictVersion` and `LooseVersion` classes; if you give it versions that would work with `StrictVersion`, then they will compare the same way. Otherwise, comparisons are more like a "smarter" form of `LooseVersion`. It is possible to create pathological version coding schemes that will fool this parser, but they should be very rare in practice.

The [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#specifying-your-project-s-version) provides some examples:

> If you want to be certain that your chosen numbering scheme works the
> way you think it will, you can use the `pkg_resources.parse_version()`
> function to compare different version numbers:
>
> ```
> >>> from pkg_resources import parse_version
> >>> parse_version('1.9.a.dev') == parse_version('1.9a0dev')
> True
> >>> parse_version('2.1-rc2') < parse_version('2.1')
> True
> >>> parse_version('0.6a9dev-r41475') < parse_version('0.6a9')
> True
> ```

Answer (score 82):

```
def versiontuple(v):
    return tuple(map(int, (v.split("."))))

>>> versiontuple("2.3.1") > versiontuple("10.1.1")
False
```

Comment: The other answers are in the standard library and follow PEP standards.

Comment: Good point.   I was able to work around this by padding each item in the tuple with leading zeros using the `zfill()` function.

Comment: This will fail for something like `versiontuple("1.0") > versiontuple("1")`. The versions are the same, but the tuples created `(1,)!=(1,0)`

Comment: In what sense are version 1 and version 1.0 the same? Version numbers aren't floats.

Comment: **No, this should _not_ be the accepted answer.** Thankfully, it isn't. Reliable parsing of version specifiers is non-trivial (if not practically infeasible) in the general case. Don't reinvent the wheel and then proceed to break it. As [ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567292/ecatmur) suggests [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11887885/2809027), just use `distutils.version.LooseVersion`. That's what it's there for.

Comment: @chris when packaging an application the other answers require you to add all of distutils or all of packaging and pkg_resources ... which are a bit of bloat.   this is a useful answer that works much of the time - and doesn't lead to package bloat.  it really depends on the context.

Comment: Despite its limitations, I have chosen this approach because I think that the version codes of the tool I want to compare versions (Git) will behave reliably, and I do not want to rely on a pip library (which may not be present in my target environment) or a deprecated library. Just to play safe, I decided to only use the first two numbers of Git's version code and disregard everything else.

Answer (score 32):

What's wrong with transforming the version string into a tuple and going from there? Seems elegant enough for me

```
>>> (2,3,1) < (10,1,1)
True
>>> (2,3,1) < (10,1,1,1)
True
>>> (2,3,1,10) < (10,1,1,1)
True
>>> (10,3,1,10) < (10,1,1,1)
False
>>> (10,3,1,10) < (10,4,1,1)
True
```

@kindall's solution is a quick example of how good the code would look.

Comment: I think this answer could be expanded upon by providing code that performs the transformation of a __PEP440__ string into a tuple. I think you will find it's not a trivial task. I think it's better left to the package that  performs that translation for `setuptools`, which is `pkg_resources`.

Comment: @TylerGubala  this is a great answer in situations where you know that the version is and always will be "simple".   pkg_resources is a big package and can cause a distributed executable to be rather bloated.

Comment: @Erik Aronesty I think version control inside of distributed executables is somewhat ouside of the scope of the question, but I agree, generally at least. I think though that there is something to be said about the reusability of `pkg_resources`, and that assumptions of simple package naming may not always be ideal.

Comment: It works great for making sure `sys.version_info > (3, 6)` or whatever.

Answer (score 19):

The way that `setuptools` does it, it uses the `pkg_resources.parse_version` function. It should be **PEP440** compliant.

Example:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Example comparing two PEP440 formatted versions
"""
import pkg_resources

VERSION_A = pkg_resources.parse_version("1.0.1-beta.1")
VERSION_B = pkg_resources.parse_version("v2.67-rc")
VERSION_C = pkg_resources.parse_version("2.67rc")
VERSION_D = pkg_resources.parse_version("2.67rc1")
VERSION_E = pkg_resources.parse_version("1.0.0")

print(VERSION_A)
print(VERSION_B)
print(VERSION_C)
print(VERSION_D)

print(VERSION_A==VERSION_B) #FALSE
print(VERSION_B==VERSION_C) #TRUE
print(VERSION_C==VERSION_D) #FALSE
print(VERSION_A==VERSION_E) #FALSE
```

Comment: `pkg_resources` is part of `setuptools`, which depends on `packaging`. See other answers that discuss `packaging.version.parse`, which has an identical implementation to `pkg_resources.parse_version`.

Comment: Moreover, it now uses packaging as vendor.

Comment: @Jed I don't think `setuptools` depends on `packaging`. I can import `setuptools` and `pkg_resources`, but `import packaging` raise ImportError.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked in 16.04.6 LTS, python3.8

Answer (score 13):

There is [packaging](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/packaging) package available, which will allow you to compare versions as per [PEP-440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/).

```
>>> from packaging.version import Version
>>> Version('1.1') < Version('1.2')
True
>>> Version('1.2.dev4+deadbeef') < Version('1.2')
True
>>> Version('1.2.8.5') <= Version('1.2')
False
>>> Version('1.2.8.5') <= Version('1.2.8.6')
True
```

`packaging` has no legacy version string support. Consider [looseversion](https://pypi.org/project/looseversion/) if you need to support strings which aren't valid PEP 440 versions.

Comment: For those wondering about the difference between `packaging.version.Version` and `packaging.version.parse`: "[`version.parse`] takes a version string and will parse it as a `Version` if the version is a valid PEP 440 version, otherwise it will parse it as a `LegacyVersion`." (whereas `version.Version` would raise `InvalidVersion`; [source](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version/#packaging.version.parse))

Comment: NB: `LooseVersion` yields a deprecation warning in 3.10: `DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 6s`

Answer (score 11):

Posting my full function based on Kindall's solution.  I was able to support any alphanumeric characters mixed in with the numbers by padding each version section with leading zeros.

While certainly not as pretty as his one-liner function, it seems to work well with alpha-numeric version numbers.  (Just be sure to set the `zfill(#)` value appropriately if you have long strings in your versioning system.)

```
def versiontuple(v):
   filled = []
   for point in v.split("."):
      filled.append(point.zfill(8))
   return tuple(filled)
```

.

```
>>> versiontuple("10a.4.5.23-alpha") > versiontuple("2a.4.5.23-alpha")
True


>>> "10a.4.5.23-alpha" > "2a.4.5.23-alpha"
False
```

Comment: Possible improvements: 1) split string by a (compiled) `[.+-]` regex (and not just `.`) 2) determine the maximum substring length and use that for zfill - see also [my gist](https://gist.github.com/gsauthof/9a00f5fb7b45ac45fcc93b7582c7590b)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [semver](https://pypi.org/project/semver/) package to determine if a version satisfies a [semantic version](https://semver.org/) requirement. This is not the same as comparing two actual versions, but is a type of comparison.

For example, version 3.6.0+1234 should be the same as 3.6.0.

```
import semver
semver.match('3.6.0+1234', '==3.6.0')
# True

from packaging import version
version.parse('3.6.0+1234') == version.parse('3.6.0')
# False

from distutils.version import LooseVersion
LooseVersion('3.6.0+1234') == LooseVersion('3.6.0')
# False
```

Comment: "To compare two versions, semver provides the `semver.compare` function."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a filter on a library version, you may use the `__version__` attribute (here an example with the jwt library):

```
from packaging import version
import jwt

if version.parse(jwt.__version__) < version.parse('2.0.0'):
    # TODO: your code
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the sys.version_info tuple:

```
assert sys.version_info >= (3, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution which wouldn't add any new dependencies. Check out the following (Python 3) solution:

```
class VersionManager:

    @staticmethod
    def compare_version_tuples(
            major_a, minor_a, bugfix_a,
            major_b, minor_b, bugfix_b,
    ):

        """
        Compare two versions a and b, each consisting of 3 integers
        (compare these as tuples)

        version_a: major_a, minor_a, bugfix_a
        version_b: major_b, minor_b, bugfix_b

        :param major_a: first part of a
        :param minor_a: second part of a
        :param bugfix_a: third part of a

        :param major_b: first part of b
        :param minor_b: second part of b
        :param bugfix_b: third part of b

        :return:    1 if a  > b
                    0 if a == b
                   -1 if a  < b
        """
        tuple_a = major_a, minor_a, bugfix_a
        tuple_b = major_b, minor_b, bugfix_b
        if tuple_a > tuple_b:
            return 1
        if tuple_b > tuple_a:
            return -1
        return 0

    @staticmethod
    def compare_version_integers(
            major_a, minor_a, bugfix_a,
            major_b, minor_b, bugfix_b,
    ):
        """
        Compare two versions a and b, each consisting of 3 integers
        (compare these as integers)

        version_a: major_a, minor_a, bugfix_a
        version_b: major_b, minor_b, bugfix_b

        :param major_a: first part of a
        :param minor_a: second part of a
        :param bugfix_a: third part of a

        :param major_b: first part of b
        :param minor_b: second part of b
        :param bugfix_b: third part of b

        :return:    1 if a  > b
                    0 if a == b
                   -1 if a  < b
        """
        # --
        if major_a > major_b:
            return 1
        if major_b > major_a:
            return -1
        # --
        if minor_a > minor_b:
            return 1
        if minor_b > minor_a:
            return -1
        # --
        if bugfix_a > bugfix_b:
            return 1
        if bugfix_b > bugfix_a:
            return -1
        # --
        return 0

    @staticmethod
    def test_compare_versions():
        functions = [
            (VersionManager.compare_version_tuples, "VersionManager.compare_version_tuples"),
            (VersionManager.compare_version_integers, "VersionManager.compare_version_integers"),
        ]
        data = [
            # expected result, version a, version b
            (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
            (1, 1, 5, 5, 0, 5, 5),
            (1, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 5),
            (1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1),
            (1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
            (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
            (0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1),  # works even with negative version numbers :)
            (0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
            (-1, 5, 5, 0, 6, 5, 0),
            (-1, 5, 5, 0, 5, 9, 0),
            (-1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6),
            (-1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 5, 8),
        ]
        count = len(data)
        index = 1
        for expected_result, major_a, minor_a, bugfix_a, major_b, minor_b, bugfix_b in data:
            for function_callback, function_name in functions:
                actual_result = function_callback(
                    major_a=major_a, minor_a=minor_a, bugfix_a=bugfix_a,
                    major_b=major_b, minor_b=minor_b, bugfix_b=bugfix_b,
                )
                outcome = expected_result == actual_result
                message = "{}/{}: {}: {}: a={}.{}.{} b={}.{}.{} expected={} actual={}".format(
                    index, count,
                    "ok" if outcome is True else "fail",
                    function_name,
                    major_a, minor_a, bugfix_a,
                    major_b, minor_b, bugfix_b,
                    expected_result, actual_result
                )
                print(message)
                assert outcome is True
                index += 1
        # test passed!


if __name__ == '__main__':
    VersionManager.test_compare_versions()
```

EDIT: added variant with tuple comparison. Of course the variant with tuple comparison is nicer, but I was looking for the variant with integer comparison

Comment: I am curious in what situation does this avoid adding dependencies? Won't you need the packaging library (used by setuptools) to create a python package?

Comment: @JosiahL. Avoiding such a dependency makes sense when you are using your code on hosts where you don't package anything (think: production server vs. developer workstation). However, this code doesn't answer the question, because it assumes that you already have decomposed/converted your version string by yourself - while the question is about comparing version strings such as `"2.3.1" > "10.1.1"`. Also, I don't see the point of wrapping this as a static method in a class.

Answer (score 0):

... and getting back to easy ...
for simple scripts you can use:

```
import sys
needs = (3, 9) # or whatever
pvi = sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor
```

later in your code

```
try:
    assert pvi >= needs
except:
    print("will fail!")
    # etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

To increment version using python

```
def increment_version(version):
    version = version.split('.')
    if int(version[len(version) - 1]) >= 99:
        version[len(version) - 1] = '0'
        version[len(version) - 2] = str(int(version[len(version) - 2]) + 1)
    else:
        version[len(version) - 1] = str(int(version[len(version) - 1]) + 1)
    return '.'.join(version)

version = "1.0.0"
version_type_2 = "1.0"
print("old version",version ,"new version",increment_version(version))
print("old version",version_type_2 ,"new version",increment_version(version_type_2))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a compact code for comparing three version numbers. Note that the string comparison fails for all pairs here.

```py
from itertools import permutations

for v1, v2 in permutations(["3.10.21", "3.10.3", "3.9.9"], 2):
    print(f"\nv1 = {v1}, v2 = {v2}")
    print(f"v1 < v2      version.parse(v1) < version.parse(v2)")
    print(f"{v1 < v2}         {version.parse(v1) < version.parse(v2)}")
```

That gives us:

```
v1='3.10.21', v2='3.10.3'
v1 < v2      version.parse(v1) < version.parse(v2)
True         False

v1='3.10.21', v2='3.9.9'
v1 < v2      version.parse(v1) < version.parse(v2)
True         False

v1='3.10.3', v2='3.10.21'
v1 < v2      version.parse(v1) < version.parse(v2)
False         True

v1='3.10.3', v2='3.9.9'
v1 < v2      version.parse(v1) < version.parse(v2)
True         False

v1='3.9.9', v2='3.10.21'
v1 < v2      version.parse(v1) < version.parse(v2)
False         True

v1='3.9.9', v2='3.10.3'
v1 < v2      version.parse(v1) < version.parse(v2)
False         True
```

`permutations(iterable, 2)` gives us all the 2-length [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) of an iterable. So for example

```py
list(permutations('ABC', 2))
```

gives us  `[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B')]`.

Answer (score -2):

similar to standard [strverscmp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strverscmp.3.html)  and similar to [this solution by Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836734/810282) but using findall instead of split to avoid empty case.

```py
import re
num_split_re = re.compile(r'([0-9]+|[^0-9]+)')

def try_int(i, fallback=None):
    try:
        return int(i)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    except TypeError:
        pass
    return fallback

def ver_as_list(a):
    return [try_int(i, i) for i in num_split_re.findall(a)]

def strverscmp_lt(a, b):
    a_ls = ver_as_list(a)
    b_ls = ver_as_list(b)
    return a_ls < b_ls
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is something that will work assuming your semantic versions are "clean" (e.g. `x.x.x`) and you have a list of versions you need to sort.

```py
# Here are some versions
versions = ["1.0.0", "1.10.0", "1.9.0"]

# This does not work
versions.sort() # Result: ['1.0.0', '1.10.0', '1.9.0']

# So make a list of tuple versions
tuple_versions = [tuple(map(int, (version.split(".")))) for version in versions]

# And sort the string list based on the tuple list
versions = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(tuple_versions, versions))] # Result: ['1.0.0', '1.9.0', '1.10.0']
```

To get the latest version you could just select the last element in the list `versions[-1]` or reverse sort by using the `reverse` attribute of `sorted()`, setting it to `True`, and getting the `[0]` element.

You could of course then wrap all this up in a convenient function for reuse.

```py
def get_latest_version(versions):
    """
    Get the latest version from a list of versions.
    """
    try:
        tuple_versions = [tuple(map(int, (version.split(".")))) for version in versions]
        versions = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(tuple_versions, versions), reverse=True)]
        latest_version = versions[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        latest_version = None

    return latest_version

print(get_latest_version(["1.0.0", "1.10.0", "1.9.0"]))
```

Comment: How is this an improvement over [kindall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11887825/427158) (posted in 2012) when comparing two version strings? It seems like you are trying to answer a different question.

Answer (score -2):

simple few-liner:

```py
import sys
if (sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor) >= (3, 9):
    ...
else:
    ...
```