# GitPython tags sorted

Tags: python, git, sorting, tags, gitpython

I am trying to get the latest tag in the repo using GitPython lib. Usually I was doing it this way:

```
repo = Repo(project_root)
last_tag = str(repo.tags[-1])
```

But once version 1.10 was released, I am always getting 1.9 ;( I know it's related to output `git tag -l` being listing same order. So it will be `1.1, 1.10, 1.2, ..., 1.9`

The question is how to get the latest tag using GitPython? (I am aware of `git tag -l | sort -V` and I know how to solve this not using the repo object. But maybe someone knows what am I missing in getting sorted tags list in this lib)

Custom sorting function is always an option too, but still, I wonder if there a way to do it with GitPython?

Comment: It is working all right for me. `python v2.7.6`, `gitpython v0.1.7`. What version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just had a look and found the [code responsible for the sorting](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/0.3/git/refs/symbolic.py#L577). Therefore I see no other way but to reverse the sorting order yourself, like

```
reversed(repo.tags)
```

If preferred, you can also use the underlying git command, and parse the result yourself, such as in this example:

```
repo.git.tag(l=True) # equals git tag -l
```

That way, whatever `git tag` can do, you can do (which could be interesting for listing tags in order of traversal, starting from a given commit).

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: None of this answers the question for me because `1.10` still erroneously shows before `1.2`.

Comment: This answer is not really correct - it assumes that the sorting of tags is in an order of creation, which it is not. Its an alphabetic sort.  `git tag --sort creatordate` OTOH will sort by tag creation date

Comment: @hewsonism this is actually exactly the answer. Git flags are passed from Python via kwargs, so `repo.git.tag(sort='creatordate').split('\n')` (with a formatting alteration) returns a list of tags sorted ascending by created date.

Answer (score 32):

The `IterableList` object returned by `repo.tags` in GitPython extends the `list` Python class, which means that you can sort it the way you want. To get the latest tag created, you can simply do:

```
import git
repo = git.Repo('path/to/repo')
tags = sorted(repo.tags, key=lambda t: t.commit.committed_datetime)
latest_tag = tags[-1]
```

Answer (score 6):

The above will work if there are different commits associated with the tags (which is generally the case). However a more accurate way would be as follows which picks up the tag date:

```
import git
repo = git.Repo('path/to/repo')
tags = sorted(repo.tags, key=lambda t: t.tag.tagged_date)
latest_tag = tags[-1]
```

Comment: This worked well, but I had to skip entries for `t.tag == None`, otherwise blam..

Answer (score 2):

The sorting is done in alphanumeric order, so "1.9" is ranked higher than "1.10" because it ordering is character wise and "9" > "1".

If you want a more sensible sorting you got two options: zero-pad your version numbers (1.09 instead of 1.9), which would be preferred but it's hard to implement it in hindsight.

The other is sorting the tags in python.
There is a library called [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) available that does natural sorts for all kinds of data.
But for this simple case you could also use the key argument of the sorting function:

```
nsort = lambda v:tuple(map(int, v.split('.')))
sorted(repo.tags, key=nsort)
```

Comment: A more flexible solution would be to use the LooseVersion class of distutils.version.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/how-do-i-compare-version-numbers-in-python/21065570) for more info.