# get a list of all tags on a remote with gitpython

Tags: python, gitpython

I would like to get a sorted list of tags on a remote with `gitpython`.

The answer here [gitpython-tags-sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056478/gitpython-tags-sorted) returns a list of the tags in the local repository.

My current solution to get the current tags from the remote is to run this command in the git shell before I list all tags with the solution above: `git fetch --prune origin "+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/`. How can I accomplish this with `gitpython`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives a undecoded string with the tags on the remote and the commit associated

```py
import git

repo = git.Repo("path_to_local_repo")

tagList=repo.git.ls_remote("--tags", "origin")
```