# How to compare kernel, software, etc. versions numbers in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, version-numbering

For a role I'm developing I need to verify that the kernel version is greater than a particular version.

I've found the `ansible_kernel` fact, but is there an easy way to compare this to other versions?  I thought I might manually explode the version string on the dots (`.`) and compare the numbers, but I can't even find a friendly filter to explode the version string out, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: for splitting, since ansible 2.0, you can `{{ variable.split('.') }}`; you can then use a loop using `with_together` to compare major, minor and patch version each other

Comment: Can you post your playbook? (whatever you have)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is a [`version` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/version_test.html) for it:

```
{{ ansible_distribution_version is version('12.04', '>=') }}
    
{{ sample_version_var is version('1.0', operator='lt', strict=True) }}
```

---

Prior to Ansible 2.5, all tests were also provided as filters, so, the same was achievable with a filter, named [`version_compare`](https://docs.ansible.com/archive/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-versions), but in current versions of Ansible, the test was renamed and, overall, the tests and filters have been clearly disambiguated

```
{{ ansible_distribution_version | version_compare('12.04', '>=') }}    
    
{{ sample_version_var | version_compare('1.0', operator='lt', strict=True) }}
```

Comment: Thanks @konstantin-suvorov. I've now found the docs on this, but can't see find an explanation of what 'strict' does.  Do you know where I can find this info?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11887885/2795592) answer about StrictVersion vs LooseVersion.

Answer (score 7):

> **To Print the host IP address if the kernel version is less than 3**

```
Ansible Version : 2.0.0.2

---
- hosts: all
  vars:
   kernel_version: "{{ ansible_kernel }}"
  tasks:
   - name: 'kernel version from facts'
     debug:
      msg: '{{ansible_all_ipv4_addresses}} {{ansible_kernel}}'
     when: ansible_kernel |  version_compare('3','<')
```

**

> In 2.5 version_compare was renamed to version

**

Comment: Though this is a late response, I feel as though this is the better answer. Can you edit your answer to include a link to the documentation as @konstantin-suvorov did to make the best answer?

Comment: version isn't a filter at least in ansible 2.9, see usage at https://github.com/systemli/ansible-role-sshd/pull/24/files

Answer (score 6):

For `ansible>=2.9` this won't work, as the test syntax is now strictly separated from filters.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html

The working solution would be:

```
{{ sample_version_var is version('1.0', operator='lt', strict=True) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare a version number, such as checking if the ansible_facts['distribution_version'] version is greater than or equal to ‘12.04’, you can use the version test.

```
{{ ansible_facts['distribution_version'] is version('12.04', '>=') }}
```

When using version in a playbook or role, don’t use {{ }} as described in the FAQ

```
vars:
    my_version: 1.2.3

tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "my_version is higher than 1.0.0"
      when: my_version is version('1.0.0', '>')
```

Check [Ansible Doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions) for more info

Answer (score -4):

Have you thought of using shell module instead? for example:

```
   - name: Get Kernel version
     shell: uname -r | egrep '^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' -o
     register: kernel_shell_output

   - debug: msg="{{ kernel_shell_output.stdout}}"

   - name: Add cstate and reboot bios if kernel is 4.8
     shell: echo "do what yo need to do"
     when: kernel_shell_output.stdout == "4.8"
```

Comment: Using shell instead of modules is ansible anti-pattern.

Comment: Also, won't comparing strings not necessarily place the version in the correct order? (I've not tests this)

Comment: Shell is one of things that you should generally try to avoid (ie. there by monsters, there)... unless there's "no other way." When there are builtin filters, like `version_compare`, there's obviously "a better way."