# Compare Ubuntu major and minor version in Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I need to dynamically install apt packages when the full Ubuntu version (Major.Minor like 18.10) is larger or smaller than a specified value. This is required to install the corrent `libvirt-bin` package, that were [renamed in 18.10](https://www.sysnettechsolutions.com/en/linux/install-kvm-qemu-linux-systems/). The fact `ansible_distribution_version` holds the numeric version and I found [the version comparision filter in an old Ansible doc](https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html#version-comparison-filters), that [seems renamed in Ansible 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997053/9428314) but it doesn't work in the latest 2.9 release:

```
- name: Execute on ubuntu 18.10 or newer
  shell: "echo Youre on Ubuntu 18.10 or newer"
  when: ansible_distribution_version | version('18.10', '>=')
```

> The conditional check 'ansible_distribution_version | version('19.10', '>=')' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'version'.

The [latest (currently 2.9) documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) doesn't contain any filter for version comparisation. I tried float-conversation, which seems to work:

```
- name: Execute on ubuntu 18.10 or newer
  shell: "echo executed on ubuntu 18.10 or newer"
  when: ansible_distribution_version | float >= 18.10
```

Are there any disadvantages of using this conversation that justifys why `version_comparisation` and `version` filters were introduced? Or is there another filter to safely compare versions that I haven't found?

Comment: Instead of using | , can you try as ansible_distribution_version is version('18.10', '>=')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using tests as filters is deprecated. Instead of using `result|version` use `result is version` (as advised in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison))

```
when: ansible_distribution_version is version('18.10', '>=')
```