# How to strip extra characters from ansible_kernel

Tags: variables, ansible, yaml, conditional-statements

I'm trying to find a way to strip the characters with respect to the ansible_kernel variable. As of now, it outputs something like this:

3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64

I just need the first 4 characters (3.10) as I'm looking to write a conditional task for kernel versions that match a specific value.

I attempted to follow the example here but, I just get a hello world as my output:

[How to compare kernel (or other) version numbers in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779802/how-to-compare-kernel-or-other-version-numbers-in-ansible)

Here is my simple code:

```
 - name: check kernel
   hosts: all
   gather_facts: yes
   vars:
      kernel_version: "{{ansible_kernel}}"
  
   tasks:
    
   - debug:
      var: kernel_version
    
   - set_fact: release="{{ kernel_version }}"
 
   - debug:
      var: release
    
   - debug: 
      msg:"Version is {{'release'[:5]}}" //also tried with release.stdout but I get an error
```

Output of play:

```
ASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [server] => {
    "kernel_version": "3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64"
}
TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [server]
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [server] => {
    "release": "3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64"
}
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [server] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use *split*. For example, split the version by dots, select the first two elements, and *join* them again

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ver: "{{ kernel_version.split('.')[:2]|join('.') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ver: '3.10'
```

Split by dash '-' and take the first element

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ver: "{{ kernel_version.split('-')|first }}"
```

gives the full version

```yaml
  ver: 3.10.0
```

---

Use [Comparing versions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions) to test versions. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: Version higher than 3.0.0
      when: ver is version('3.0.0', '>')
    - debug:
        msg: Version lower than 3.0.0
      when: ver is version('3.0.0', '<')
```

give

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Version higher than 3.0.0

TASK [debug] ****
skipping: [localhost]
```

Comment: Wow!!! I'll try this in the new year and get back to you to mark it as the correct answer!!

Comment: Decided to try this now. Worked like a charm!!!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you could do it. Try:

```
 - name: check kernel
   hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: yes  
   tasks:
     - debug:
         msg: "Stripped version {{ ansible_kernel[0:4] }}"
     - debug:
         msg: "The version is greater 0.2: {{ ansible_kernel is version_compare('0.2', operator='gt') }}"
     - debug:
         msg: "The version is smaller 0.2: {{ ansible_kernel is version_compare('0.2', operator='lt') }}"
```

The first one demonstrates how you could get the first 4 characters. It is unsuitable for your purpose, though (what about the version `3.1.4` -> would yield `3.1.`

You should go with `version_compare` (see the other examples). Since ansible 2.9 this is the right syntax

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I'll also try this as well just for fun.

Comment: If it solves your problem, please don't forget to accept (green checkmark) the question