# ansible compare kernel versions with "generic" in them

Tags: ansible

After reading this and working on what I found there: [How to compare kernel (or other) version numbers in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779802/how-to-compare-kernel-or-other-version-numbers-in-ansible) I ran into a problem.

What if the kernel version is something like: `4.15.0-173-generic` ?

If I do something like this:

```
    - name: Compare kernel version
      set_fact:
        checks_out: "{{ ansible_kernel is version('4.15.0-173.456', '>=') }}"
```

This gives an error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "Version comparison: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"}
```

When checking for specific kernel versions, for instance for the purpose of investigating if an host is vulnerable to a CVE, this is hindering.

If I remove the `.456` it works, but I feel like this is going to be a situation where the generic kernel still needs to be updated and rebooted.

How I do get I around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```yaml
    - name: Compare kernel version
      set_fact:
        checks_out: "{{ ansible_facts.kernel | replace('-generic', '') is version('4.15.0-173.456', '>=') }}"
```