# regex to check version

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying write the code to check the version format in regex.  Is this the correct way to check the format

v0.0.0 -> `\w\d[0-9].\d[0-9].\d[0-9]`

Also, how do I compare using python and selenium web driver?

```
    def version(self):
    version = self.getElement("id","version")
    match = re.search(r'\w\d\.\d\.\d', version)
    if match:
        version = match.group()
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: What happens when you test it?  Do you have reasons to think it is not correct?

Comment: `\d` and `[0-9]` mean the same thing, and `.` matches any character.  I would check for version like `v\d+\.\d+\.\d+` https://regex101.com/r/HbLJoi/1

Comment: Consider adding capture groups to the expression.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHaugh.  I know I'm missing something. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: An Out Of Topic: Have you tried the parsers for the version? Just in case you need only to parse version and don't implement the relative regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/compare-version-strings

Comment: No I didn't. this is what I did                                                                                 `match = re.search(r'v\d+\.\d+\.\d+', version_From_Page)
        if match:
            version = match.group()
            return True
        return False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to check each number individually? If so, you can use `v(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)` and look at each `re` group and compare.

`.` will match any character so you need to escape (`\`) it and `\d` already matches a single digit as it's equivalent to `[0-9]`.