# Append value to out of range list

Tags: python

I have a text file which contains a string. In this string there are some numbers which parse out by using regex. After the regex I get this as an output:

> 0.7.3.4

But lets assume that in another string i get this outout:

> 0.7.3

In this case I want to ad 00 in the end.

When I do:

```
lst = get_values.split('.')
print lst[0] -> 0
print lst[1] -> 7
print lst[2] -> 3
print lst[3] -> out of range obviously
```

So I wanna check if lst[3] is out range, then add "00" to it. Same goes for lst[2] and lst[1]. Here is "dummy pseudo code":

```
if not lst[3]:
    add "00"
```

The end output should look like this in the end:

> 070304

or maybe like this is a lst[x] is missing:

> 070300

And the first "0" is also removed just in case you wonder where it was.

Comment: `if len(lst) == 3: lst.append("00")`?

Comment: Are you trying to compare version numbers? Because there are [tools for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11887762/1258041).

Comment: @LevLevitsky Nope, not comparing version number. More like checking if each item has a value.

Comment: @user535081 should the output for `0.7` be `0700` or `070000`?

Comment: @ZevAverbach It should be 070000. See Paco H. answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
def format_string(str):
    parts = [0, 0, 0]
    for idx, num in enumerate(str.split('.')[1:]):
        parts[idx] = int(num)
    return '%02d%02d%02d' % tuple(parts)

print(format_string('0.7.3.4'))
print(format_string('0.7.3'))
```

Output:

```
070304
070300
```

If you want to make it more customizable:

```
def format_string(str, expected_parts=3, ignore_parts=1):
    input_parts = str.split('.')[ignore_parts:]
    output_parts = ['00'] * expected_parts

    for idx, num in enumerate(input_parts):
        output_parts[idx] = '%02d' % int(num)

    return ''.join(output_parts)
```