# comparing strings of different lengths

Tags: python, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare strings in Python that can be different lengths. This is to do a simple version check.
Here are the examples: `1.2.3, 1.2.15, 1.2.2a`

I need to compare to find which one is bigger so taking example above `1.2.2a < 1.2.3 < 1.2.15`. If there were only number than it would be pretty simple but the added character messes things as it is not always present. I thought that converting to base64 which makes string the same length will solve the problem but with base64 1.2.15 becomes less than 1.2.2a and 1.2.3.
Maybe there is a module that already does that.
Thank you.

Comment: You probable want to look at the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) - regular expressions will be able to isolate the letter from the numbers. What would happen, for example, if you got 1.2.2a and 1.2.2b?

Comment: *"base64 which makes string the same length"*? Wat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version numbers you are using appear to confirm with the [*semantic versioning*](http://semver.org/) standard. There are libraries available to handle this for you - take a look at [`semver`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/semver) or [`semantic_version`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/semantic_version/).

Comment: Welcome to SO. If this answered your question (unless, of course, someone answers it better :-)) please feel free to mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). In this case it appears the question may be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/compare-version-strings-in-python) which may give you some more ideas.

Comment: Thanks for quick response this is what I was looking for.