# How to compare version strings in salt sls files

Tags: salt-stack

Does saltstack have an equivalent to puppets versioncmp() function?  Or alternatively, is there a way to get the distutils.version or packaging.version.parse methods (as mentioned on [Compare version strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/compare-version-strings-in-python)) available in a jinja+yaml rendered sls file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the module `pkg.version_cmp`:

```
# salt-call pkg.version_cmp '1.0.2' '1.1.1'
local:
    -1
# salt-call pkg.version_cmp '0.2.4.1-0ubuntu1' '0.2.4-0ubuntu1'
local:
    1
```

Inside jinja you can use it in a way similar to:

```
{% if salt['pkg.version_cmp']('1.1.0','1.0.5') > 0 %}
  ....
{% endif %}
```

Comment: See [here](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.aptpkg.html#salt.modules.aptpkg.version_cmp) for some documentation on the `version_cmp` function. Note that the exact module used varies (see [here](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.pkg.html))