# Compare version numbers using jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, salt-stack

I am using jinja2 template to install/upgrade packages.

The logic was setting a variable for current installed version and compare it with the available version. It was working fine but once we passed in to 10.x, comparison quit working.

Is it possible to cast the variable so it can correctly identify 10.9.8 is greater than 9.8.7?

Thanks

`current_version=['9.8.7']`

`{% if current_version < '10.9.8' %}`

Comment: I guess I can try to remove the dots and cast them to integer and then compare. How would one go about deleting dots in jinja2?

Comment: I ended up using != to compare installed version string to the version I want to have installed on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare version strings in salt sls files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701907/how-to-compare-version-strings-in-salt-sls-files)

Answer (score 18):

When using Ansible, there's a special test [version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions) (named `version_compare` before Ansible 2.5):

```
{% if current_version | version('10.9.8', '<') %}
```

`current_version` should be string (it is a list in your example).

Comment: Very good to know. This specific use case is deployed with salt-stack. Apparently "version_compare" filter is not implemented in salt-stack. Thank you for response.

Comment: Why did you put `ansible` tag in this case?

Comment: this is ansible only

Comment: For Ansible > 2.5, version_compare has been replaced by version.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in Ansible Jinja templates

Answer (score 2):

Using plain jinja2, without ansible or other extensions:

```
{% if my_version.split('.') | map('int') | list >= [10, 9, 8]  %}
```

By converting each element to `int`, you ensure it won't compare lexicographically.

Answer (score 1):

### With Jinja2

Using [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) and because of how [sequence comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) work, the following should do just fine:

```
{% if current_version.split('.') | map('int') < '10.9.8'.split('.') | map('int') %}
```

Test:

```
Split: {{ current_version.split('.') }}
Split + cast: {{ current_version.split('.') | map('int') }}
---
Is {{ current_version.split('.') | map('int') }} < {{ '10.9.8'.split('.') | map('int') }}?
{% if current_version.split('.') | map('int') < '10.9.8'.split('.') | map('int') %}
Yes
{% endif %}
```

Which, with `current_version: "9.8.7"` gives:

```
Split: ['9', '8', '7']
Split + cast: [9, 8, 7]
---
Is [9, 8, 7] < [10, 9, 8]?
Yes
```

Comment: This solution fails the exactly same way as OP's. `['1','2'] < ['1','10'] == False`

Comment: Ah, good catch, you are right. It missed the `int` cast, now it should work. Let me know if there's another problem.

Answer (score 1):

@cglacet answer was useful and worked when generating in Ansible, but it gave me an error when using the Jinja2 library directly in Python:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'>=' not supported between instances of 'generator' and 'generator'
```

It seems like it prints the memory location and not actual values. I don't know what voodoo magic Ansible used to make it work, but adding a `| list` creates an actual list of integers and fixes the issue.

```
{% if current_version.split('.') | map('int') | list < '10.9.8'.split('.') | map('int') | list %}
```

---

Proof:

```
{% set sw_version = "7.5.2" %}
{{ sw_version.split('.') }}
{{ ['7', '5', '2'] | int }}
{{ sw_version.split('.') | map('int') }}
```

output

```
['7', '5', '2']
0
<generator object sync_do_map at 0x1223b6270>
```

Fix:

```
{% set sw_version = "7.5.2" %}

{% if sw_version.split('.') | map('int') | list < '10.9.8'.split('.') | map('int') | list %}
Smaller than to 10.9.8
{% endif %}
{% if sw_version.split('.') | map('int') | list >= '7.5.2'.split('.') | map('int') | list %}
Equal to 7.5.2
{% endif %}
{% if sw_version.split('.') | map('int') | list >= '6.7.5'.split('.') | map('int') | list %}
Bigger than 6.7.5
{% endif %}
{% if sw_version.split('.') | map('int') | list < '7.6.1'.split('.') | map('int') | list %}
Smaller than 7.6.1
{% endif %}
{% if sw_version.split('.') | map('int') | list < '7.5.10'.split('.') | map('int') | list %}
Smaller than 7.5.10
{% endif %}
```

```
Smaller than to 10.9.8


Equal to 7.5.2


Bigger than 6.7.5


Smaller than 7.6.1


Smaller than 7.5.10
```

Answer (score 0):

In saltstack you can use `pkg.version_cmp`

See my reply here: [How to compare version strings in salt sls files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701907/how-to-compare-version-strings-in-salt-sls-files/46022484#46022484)