# How to compare version numbers of software using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Hey I am trying to check the version on installed software on my VMs with Ansible.

Unfortunately I cant get the conditionals right.

Via the `ansible_facts.packages` I get the version of the software but I am not sure about the comparing.

```yaml
- hosts:
    - os_linux

  vars:
    softwareVersion: "4.8.0-49"

  tasks:

  - name: Gather the package facts
    ansible.builtin.package_facts:
      manager: auto

  - name: Check version of SoftwareX
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "OLD SoftwareX version: {{ ansible_facts.packages['SoftwareX'][0]['version'] }} found"
    when: "ansible_facts.packages['SoftwareX'][0]['version'] <= {{ softwareVersion }}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I am not sure about the comparing.*
>
> `when: "ansible_facts.packages['SoftwareX'][0]['version'] <= {{ softwareVersion }}"`

Since according [When should I use `{{ }}`?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)

> *`when:`... are always templated and you should avoid adding {{ }}.*

you'll need to remove first the curly brackets from `softwareVersion`.

Then, since you are comparing strings which contains a version number in order, you need to address this in a different way. Means, you can't use plain a mathematical operation but instead a specific filter for.

A minimal test playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    installedVersion: "4.7.0-48"
    softwareVersion: "4.8.0-49"

  tasks:

  - name: Show hint
    debug:
      msg: "OLD"
    when: installedVersion is version(softwareVersion, '<=')
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show hint] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: OLD
```

**Further Documentaion**

- [Comparing versions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions)

> *Note: In 2.5 `version_compare` was renamed to `version`*
>
> *To compare a version number, such as checking if the `ansible_facts['distribution_version']` version is greater than or equal to ‘12.04’, you can use the `version` test.*

**Similar Q&A**

- [Compare version numbers using Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46326233/6771046)
- [How to compare kernel (or other) version numbers in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39784985/6771046)