# Ansible playbook to compare package versions and send alert

Tags: ansible

I am having 1 node where the multiple (deb) packages are deployed. I want to check the version if correct one is deployed or not, if miss match i have to receive alert.

```
---
- hosts: hostname
  become: yes
  vars:
    expected_version: "1.1.1"
  tasks:
    - name: Get package versions
      ansible.builtin.shell: dpkg -s {{ item }} | grep Version | awk '{print $2}'
      loop:
        - package1
        - package2
        - package3
      register: response

    - name: Display and compare package versions
      debug:
        msg: "Package version for {{ item.item }}: {{ item.stdout }}"
      loop: "{{ response.results }}"
      when: item.stdout != expected_version
      register: version_mismatch

    - name: Send email if version mismatch is found
      mail:
        host: "smtp.gmail.com"
        port: 587
        username: "someone@email.com"
        password: "password"
        to: "some@email.com"
        subject: "Version Mismatch Found"
        body: >-
          Version mismatch found for the following packages:

          {% for item in version_mismatch.results %}{{ item.item }}: {{ item.item.stdout }}
          {% endfor %}
      when: version_mismatch.results | length > 0 and version_mismatch.results is defined
      delegate_to: localhost
```

when i tried to print only ```{{ item.stdout }}`` I can see as "msg": "1.1.1"

Now if i am executing this playbook i am getting alerts though my version is matching.

Comment: In order to [Compare package versions in an Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75747047/6771046) it is recommended to use [`package_facts` module – Package information as facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use the filter difference i guess :

```
- name: Display and compare package versions
  debug:
    msg: "Package version for {{ item.item }}: {{ item.stdout }}"
  loop: "{{ response.results }}"
  register: version_info

- name: Find version differences
  set_fact:
    version_diff: "{{ version_info.results | map(attribute='stdout') | difference([expected_version]) }}"
```

Take the stdout and look difference with expected version.

Try to change your body loop :

```
  {% for item in version_info.results %}
  {% if item.stdout not in [expected_version] %}
  {{ item.item }}: {{ item.stdout }}
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  when: version_diff | length > 0
```

I haven't tested this code, but using the difference filter could be a good way.

Other way i haven't try is this module of ansible https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html

Answer (score 2):

Declare packages and versions you want to audit. For example,

```yaml
    audit:
      gtar: '1.35'
      pkg: '1.20'
      sudo: '1.10'
```

Get the packages

```yaml
    - package_facts:
```

and declare the dictionary

```yaml
  pv: "{{ dict(ansible_facts.packages|dict2items|
               json_query('[].[key, value[].version]')) }}"
```

gives, for example

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
  pv:
    gettext-runtime: ['0.22']
    gtar: ['1.35']
    indexinfo: [0.3.1]
    libffi: [3.4.4]
    mpdecimal: [2.5.1]
    perl5: [5.34.1]
    pkg: [1.20.8]
    python38: [3.8.18]
    readline: [8.2.1]
    sudo: [1.9.14p3]
ok: [test_03] => 
  pv:
    gettext-runtime: ['0.22']
    gtar: ['1.35']
    indexinfo: [0.3.1]
    libffi: [3.4.4]
    mpdecimal: [2.5.1]
    perl5: [5.34.1]
    pkg: [1.20.8]
    python38: [3.8.18]
    readline: [8.2.1]
    sudo: [1.9.14p3]
ok: [test_02] => 
  pv:
    gettext-runtime: ['0.22']
    gtar: ['1.35']
    indexinfo: [0.3.1]
    libffi: [3.4.4]
    mpdecimal: [2.5.1]
    perl5: [5.34.1]
    pkg: [1.20.8]
    python38: [3.8.18]
    readline: [8.2.1]
    sudo: [1.9.14p3]
```

Test the [versions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions). Fit the operator to your needs

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        audit_result: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for p,v in audit.items() %}
          {{ p }}:
          {% for i in pv[p] %}
          - {{ i is version(v, '>=') }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
  audit_result:
    gtar:
    - true
    pkg:
    - true
    sudo:
    - false
ok: [test_02] => 
  audit_result:
    gtar:
    - true
    pkg:
    - true
    sudo:
    - false
ok: [test_03] => 
  audit_result:
    gtar:
    - true
    pkg:
    - true
    sudo:
    - false
```

Create the dictionary audit_mismatch

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        audit_mismatch: "{{ audit_result|dict2items|
                            rejectattr('value', 'any')|
                            map(attribute='key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_02] => 
  audit_mismatch:
  - sudo
ok: [test_01] => 
  audit_mismatch:
  - sudo
ok: [test_03] => 
  audit_mismatch:
  - sudo
```

Send an email if there are any items in *audit_mismatch*

```yaml
    - mail:
        host: localhost
        to: admin
        subject: Version Mismatch Found
        body: |
          Version mismatch found for the following packages:
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {% if hostvars[host]['audit_mismatch']|length > 0 %}
          {{ host }}: {{ hostvars[host]['audit_mismatch']|join(',') }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      when: ansible_play_hosts|
            map('extract', hostvars, 'audit_mismatch')|
            flatten|length > 0
```

gives

```yaml
From: root@ctrl.example.com
To: admin@ctrl.example.com
Cc: 
Subject: Version Mismatch Found
Date: Fri, 10 Nov 2023 02:21:35 +0100
X-Mailer: Ansible mail module

Version mismatch found for the following packages:
test_01: sudo
test_02: sudo
test_03: sudo
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    pv: "{{ dict(ansible_facts.packages|dict2items|
                 json_query('[].[key, value[].version]')) }}"

    audit:
      gtar: '1.35'
      pkg: '1.20'
      sudo: '1.10'

  tasks:

    - package_facts:
    - debug:
        var: pv|to_yaml

    - set_fact:
        audit_result: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for p,v in audit.items() %}
          {{ p }}:
          {% for i in pv[p] %}
          - {{ i is version(v, '>=') }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
    - debug:
        var: audit_result

    - set_fact:
        audit_mismatch: "{{ audit_result|dict2items|
                            rejectattr('value', 'any')|
                            map(attribute='key') }}"
    - debug:
        var: audit_mismatch

    - mail:
        host: localhost
        to: admin
        subject: Version Mismatch Found
        body: |
          Version mismatch found for the following packages:
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {% if hostvars[host]['audit_mismatch']|length > 0 %}
          {{ host }}: {{ hostvars[host]['audit_mismatch']|join(',') }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      when: ansible_play_hosts|
            map('extract', hostvars, 'audit_mismatch')|
            flatten|length > 0
```