# python increment version number by 0.0.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

We are using versioning. The current version is 0.2.3
i would like to increment by 0.0.1 using python. 
Getting below error.

tagNumber = 0.2.3
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: try as a string, or a list.

Comment: Python understands versions and makes manipulation of them quite easy - please have a look at the other question linked.

Comment: you can use my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70940341/11567596

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def increment_ver(version):
    version = version.split('.')
    version[2] = str(int(version[2]) + 1)
    return '.'.join(version)
```