# Finding the latest version number in a pandas series/column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new to python. I want to map to the latest version. If there are two versions in Software_Version column always need to choose the second one which is the latest version.

```
Sofware_Component     Software_Version 

Python                     2.7
Python                     2.7,3.6
R                          3.5.0,3.6.0
R                          3.5.0
```

Code to replace the latest version:

```
result4.loc[result4['COMPONENT_VERSION'].str.contains(',')] = result4['COMPONENT_VERSION'].str.split(',').str[-1]

ERROR:ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

Code to map which is working fine

```
result4['Software_Componenet'] = result4['SOFTWARE_COMPONENT'].map(str)+' '+result4['COMPONENT_VERSION'].map(str)
```

I am expecting the result as below

```
Software_Component
Python 2.7
Python 3.6
R 3.6.0
R 3.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11887885/4909087), you can call `distutils.version.LooseVersion` iteratively from `max` inside a list comprehension:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

[max(vers.split(','), key=LooseVersion) for vers in df['Software_Version']]
# ['2.7', '3.6', '3.6.0', '3.5.0']

df['Software_Version'] = [
    max(vers.split(','), key=LooseVersion) for vers in df['Software_Version']
]
df

  Sofware_Component Software_Version
0            Python              2.7
1            Python              3.6
2                 R            3.6.0
3                 R            3.5.0
```

---

If you fancy a more pandaic version (although this'd be slower), you can `split` and `apply`:

```
df['Software_Version'].str.split(',').apply(max, key=LooseVersion)

0      2.7
1      3.6
2    3.6.0
3    3.5.0
Name: Software_Version, dtype: object
```

---

To join them together into a single column, use `agg`:

```
df.agg(' '.join, axis=1)

0    Python 2.7
1    Python 3.6
2       R 3.6.0
3       R 3.5.0
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  But I am getting an error.  AttributeError: 'LooseVersion' object has no attribute 'version'

Comment: @PCH This works for me in python3.6, can you tell me your python version so I can look into this?