# How to cut substrings of a list like from s[0][i:j] by splitting from dots?

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

Sorry it's very complicated to tell this in English for me. Here is my problem. I have this list:

```
s=["2.11", "4.7.0", "1.3", "2.2", "0.1", "1.2.5", "1.3.1", "2.7"]
```

I want these numbers ordered by from smallest to biggest. But not mathematicallly, not quite. For version numbers concept.

Think them as like version numbers. Not ordinary math. For ordinary math, 2.2>2.11 but for program version numbers concept, it's 2.11>2.2 So I need to somehow order them like that. First thing came in my mind was this. Maybe get those 11, 7, 3, 2 numbers from there that is split from dots. Then compare them, problem is how to get them out? I tried various solutions from stackoverflow. For example 2.11's 11 is this :

```
print(s[0][2:len(s[0])]) # prints 11
```

Since this list is actually two dimentional array like you, many solutions don't work for me. Please help. Or am I missing something? Is there a much simpler way to do this?

Expected output is below. Think that this returns from a function:

```
0.1,1.2.5,1.3,1.3.1,2.2,2.7,2.11,4.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
s=["2.11", "4.7.0", "1.3", "2.2", "0.1", "1.2.5", "1.3.1", "2.7"]
res = sorted(s, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split("."))))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['0.1', '1.2.5', '1.3', '1.3.1', '2.2', '2.7', '2.11', '4.7.0']
```

The idea is to compare the strings using the key parameter of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), from the documentation (emphasis mine):

> **key** specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
> comparison key from each element in iterable (for example,
> key=str.lower). The default value is None (compare the elements
> directly).

In this case the key parameter splits the string by `"."` and convert each sub string to a an integer, for example:

```
"0.1" -> (0, 1)
"2.2" -> (2, 2)
"2.11" -> (2, 11)
```

As an alternative use:

```
res = sorted(s, key=lambda x: [int(xi) for xi in x.split(".")])
```

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/how-do-i-compare-version-numbers-in-python/21065570) you can find more ideas for key parameter of `sorted` (how to compare version numbers in Python). If the version is PEP440 compliant you could use [`packaging.version.parse`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version.html#packaging.version.parse):

```
from packaging.version import parse

s = ["2.11", "4.7.0", "1.3", "2.2", "0.1", "1.2.5", "1.3.1", "2.7"]
res = sorted(s, key=parse)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['0.1', '1.2.5', '1.3', '1.3.1', '2.2', '2.7', '2.11', '4.7.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

So this, should work

```py
# as version numbers, so 2.7.2 is less than 2.7.11 for example.
s = ["2.11", "4.7.0", "1.3", "2.2", "0.1", "1.2.5", "1.3.1", "2.7"]

# sort the list of versions numbers
s.sort(key=lambda x: list(map(int, x.split('.'))))
print(s)
```

as of python>=3.8 I think that `map` returns an iterator so we need to cast it into a list manually

Answer (score 0):

One way using `distutils.version.LooseVersion`.

If they are *like version*, let them be handled as versions.

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

sorted(s, key=LooseVersion)
```

Output:

```
['0.1', '1.2.5', '1.3', '1.3.1', '2.2', '2.7', '2.11', '4.7.0']
```