# Import "pkg_resources" could not be resolved from source Pylance (reportMissingModuleSource)

Tags: python

I have python 3.8.10 (32-bit) and 3.9.7 (64.bit) installed on my system:

I am trying to compare two version strings in Python so I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/how-do-i-compare-version-numbers-in-python), especially below:

```
from pkg_resources import packaging

packaging.version.parse("0.1.1rc1") < packaging.version.parse("0.1.1rc2")
```

I am using VS Code and for some reason it says pkg_resources cannot be resolved.

I have installed packaging package in my system using below for both python versions:

```
py -m pip install packaging
python -m pip install packaging
```

and also setuptools:

```
py -m pip install setuptools
python -m pip install setuptools
```

However from python terminal, if i do "from pkg_resources import packaging" it works.

Below the list of packages installed for each python version.

python 3.9.7: py -m pip list

[image]

python 3.8.10: python -m pip list

[image]

Comment: the code should be 
```
from packaging import version
version.parse(...)
```

Comment: @MrE using from packaging import version i get the same error, packaging module cannot be resolved.

Comment: @MrE I think it is a problem related to VS Code as if I execute my script it is working.

Comment: did you select the right Python interpreter where you installed the package?