# How can I compare A app and B app version on android? without market

Tags: android

A app and B app same app.
only different version

recently my phone have A app
and my server have B app.

I want if my server have recently version 
change app .

How can I do?

use BufferedReader ?

thanks

Comment: want some more details, you can use some webservice call in your app to check if version on server is newer as app. and if yes then prompt for update or any user intimation

Comment: you can see if this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469147/get-android-apk-file-versionname-or-versioncode-without-installing-apk

Answer (score 0):

this will get the current App version

```
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo pInfo = null;
    try {
        pInfo = manager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String cuurentVersion = pInfo.versionName;
```

and you can do some version check on server by a webservice.. That you have to do

Comment: Sorry ? @조현욱 Didnt understand?

Comment: Yes you can use this in you code.. Without assessing the market @조현욱

Comment: It checks the version from the package version name.. . .:) That is from the gradle file @조현욱

Comment: oh. this code is my app version check. right?     and My server app version check use BufferedReader?

Comment: Yes, That you have to write some web service.. which returns the version details from sever .. @조현욱

Comment: but in apk status , can I find version information ?