# Android app version error

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I get an error when trying to build and deploy an app. 
I have an existing application on the device of version 1.0.0. When I'll try to build and deploy to device with an higher number I get an error message that an app with a higher version is already installed.

So to be sure that this wasn't the issue, I tried to deploy an app with version 999.999.999. Still the same error:

[image: Screenshot Android Studio]

The current application is made in Cordova (PhoneGap), the new app in Android Studio but that shouldn't be an issue. It's not possible to say "OK" because we need the data in the old app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase your `version code` instead of `version name`. That will solve your problem. `Version name` is the version to the user. `Version code` is your actual version number.

Comment: This answer helped me solve my issues, thank you!
Also I had to check my versioncode of the other app. I did it using `aapt dump badging myapp.apk` found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469147/get-android-apk-file-versionname-or-versioncode-without-installing-apk