# How do I get the versionCode and versionName (badging) of an Android AAB file?

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest, android-app-bundle

Similar to [Get Android .apk file VersionName or VersionCode WITHOUT installing apk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13469147/9636), I want to get the `versionCode` and/or `versionName` with just an [`.aab`](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) file.

I've tried simply using [the classic answer for `.apk` files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275809/9636), but substituting my `.aab` file instead, and it didn't work:

```
$ $ANDROID_HOME/sdk/build-tools/29.0.2/aapt dump badging my_aab.aab
ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found
```

I also tried attempting to dump the `xmltree` directly:

```
$ $ANDROID_HOME/sdk/build-tools/29.0.2/aapt dump xmltree my_aab.aab base/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml
W/ResourceType(39872): Bad XML block: header size 664 or total size 118110474 is larger than data size 35953
ERROR: Resource base/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt
```

I'd like to do this with the plain Android SDK, and not install any external tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.aab` files store their `xml` in a [protocol buffer format](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-app-bundle-aab-98de6dad8ba8):

> There is manifest folder having Android Manifest.xml file in the apk it is in binary format but in .aab it is real XML file compiled into a protocol buffer format because this allows to transform it easily.

And `aapt2` has a `convert` `subcommand` that `Converts an apk between binary and proto formats.`, and it will convert a `.apk` file that contains only an `AndroidManifest.xml` in proto format. Thus:

```
# Extract the AndroidManifest.xml directly
# without -p, unzip will recreate the directory structure.
unzip -p my_aab.aab base/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml > AndroidManifest.xml
# Create a dummy .apk with the proto-formatted AndroidManifest.xml
zip proto_version.apk AndroidManifest.xml
# Convert the proto-formatted AndroidManifest.xml into an apk-formatted XML
aapt2 convert proto_version.apk -o version.apk
# Now dump the badging
# I don't know why, but dump badging fails, so add `|| true` to make it succeed
aapt dump badging version.apk || true
```

Unfortunately, the final command doesn't succeed:

```
W/ResourceType(42965): No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f100000
AndroidManifest.xml:47: error: ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute value reference does not exist
```

But it does print the `versionName` and `versionCode` as expected. You can ignore the failure with `|| true`, or you can use the `dump xmltree` subcommand to dump the raw XML, which succeeds:

```
aapt dump xmltree version.apk AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 31):

Bundletool has a command to dump the manifest of the AAB in XML, and even extract specific attributes of the manifest using xpath.

```
bundletool dump manifest --bundle bundle.aab
```

And to extract just the versionCode:

```
bundletool dump manifest --bundle bundle.aab --xpath /manifest/@android:versionCode
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful, but I was trying to find a way to show it with just the vanilla Android SDK, and `bundletool` isn't in the vanilla Android SDK.

Comment: bundletool is mentionned in Android doc : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool