# Java function / api for version checking programs

Tags: java, version

I've tried to google the answer but I keep getting results relating to version compatibility and checking with Java itself.

What I'm looking for is a method or api in java that will take two dotted versions, a program version and a minimum version (1.2.1.3 and 2.1.3.4 for example ) and test if the program version meets or exceeds the minimum version.

I know this is easy enough to implement in a basic manner but I'm hoping for something which has already taken into account the cases that might not occur to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you compare two version Strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My google-fu is better than yours  :)

[Efficient way to compare version strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701948/efficient-way-to-compare-version-strings-in-java)

[How do you compare two version Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks it's not an api but at least others have been here :)