# How to check if version name String(found) > String specified for version name in Android

Tags: java, android, string

In my application I want to check the version number from the server and when this **versionName** > **myVersionName** show a `dialog`.

**verionName** is from the server comes as `"version": "1.0.0.1"` , and myVersionName is like `1.0.0.2`.

I want that when  **1.0.0.1 > 1.0.0.2** show a `dialog`.

But this **verionNames** are **Strings**. how can I check this in **String**?

Please help me

Comment: take a look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java

Comment: `String.compareTo()` compares in lexicographical order which should work just fine with your version numbers. Note that it works with the current, simple version numbers, no guarantees it will work when versioning changes to like 10.0.0.1 or 1.0.0.1.1

Comment: how can server `versionName` be smaller than the `app'sversionname` ? even if it is ...you have to update the server versionName ? just after the release !

Comment: @Ben, can you send to me code my friend? because I am amateur and really need your help. please

Comment: @Ben, until you use `"1.0.01.3".compareTo("1.0.1.2")`. This will be a problem. (Strange notation but seen somewhere... can't remember where)

Comment: @AxelH yep. It only works if the versions are lexicographically comparable. But if they are it's a fast solution. Definitely not something I would bet my code's well-being on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6702029/3395198

Comment: I agree @Ben, we could easily use a regex to sanitize this notation first and keep the Comparable usage.

Comment: I did write [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134567/4391450) with a quick class to use this logic. This should be quit efficient for most case.