# Compare version strings in groovy

Tags: string, groovy, compare

Hey I have created a Groovy script that will extract the version numbers of some folder. I would then like to compare the version numbers and select the highest.

I got my script to run through the dir folder and I then get the versions in this format: `02.2.02.01`

So I could get something like this:

- 02.2.02.01
- 02.2.02.02
- 02.2.03.01

I don't have them as a list but like this:

```
baseDir.listFiles().each { file -> 
  def string = file.getName().substring(5, 15)
  // do stuff
}
```

Also I have tested that Groovy could compare them with the `>` operator and it can! But now I need to select the one with the highest version

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This appears to work

```
String mostRecentVersion(List versions) {
  def sorted = versions.sort(false) { a, b -> 

    List verA = a.tokenize('.')
    List verB = b.tokenize('.')
     
    def commonIndices = Math.min(verA.size(), verB.size())
    
    for (int i = 0; i < commonIndices; ++i) {
      def numA = verA[i].toInteger()
      def numB = verB[i].toInteger()
      
      if (numA != numB) {
        return numA <=> numB
      }
    }
    
    // If we got this far then all the common indices are identical, so whichever version is longer must be more recent
    verA.size() <=> verB.size()
  }
  
  println "sorted versions: $sorted"
  sorted[-1]
}
```

Here is an inadequate set of tests. You should add some more.

```
assert mostRecentVersion(['02.2.02.01', '02.2.02.02', '02.2.03.01']) == '02.2.03.01' 
assert mostRecentVersion(['4', '2']) == '4'
assert mostRecentVersion(['4.1', '4']) == '4.1'
assert mostRecentVersion(['4.1', '5']) == '5'
```

Run this code and the tests in the Groovy console to verify that it works

Comment: +1 It should be noted that the `mostRecentVersion` method will leave the `versions` parameter sorted after it has been executed (as `List.sort` mutates the list by default).  If this is not wanted, you can (in groovy 1.8.1+) call: `def sorted = versions.sort(false) { a, b -> `

Comment: @tim_yates Couldn't you just let me enjoy my moment of triumph? Oh no, you had to nitpick. I have grudgingly updated my answer to include your suggestion, thanks :)

Comment: Hahaha...sorry ;-)  *shuffles off back to his desk*

Comment: Good answer! You may use the Collection's [`max(Comparable)`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#max%28java.util.Comparator%29) method if you prefer to keep the original list unmodified (and make the method's complexity linear ;)... not that it really matters in this case I would guess hehe)

Answer (score 16):

If we're going for the shortest answer, this must come close ;-)

```
String mostRecentVersion( List versions ) {
  versions.sort( false ) { a, b ->
    [a,b]*.tokenize('.')*.collect { it as int }.with { u, v ->
      [u,v].transpose().findResult{ x,y-> x<=>y ?: null } ?: u.size() <=> v.size()
    }
  }[-1]
}
```

Comment: +1 because there just aren't many people who will proudly proclaim their shortness in a public forum. Good for you.

Answer (score 7):

Mine is the shortest! lol )

```
versions = versions.sort {a, b ->
  def a1 = a.tokenize('.')*.toInteger(), b1 = b.tokenize('.')*.toInteger()
  for (i in 0..<[a1.size(), b1.size()].min()) 
    if (a1[i] != b1[i]) return a1[i] <=> b1[i]
  0
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is using Grails (e.g. Grails 2.2.3), I think VersionComparator already provides exactly what we need.

If you are not using Grails, you can always Google the source code of this class.

Example of working tests:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.VersionComparator

assert ['1.13.4', '1.4.5'].sort( new VersionComparator() ) == ['1.4.5', '1.13.4']
assert ['3.1.20', '3', '3.0.1', '3.1'].sort( new VersionComparator() ) == ['3', '3.0.1', '3.1', '3.1.20']
assert ['02.2.02.02', '02.2.03.01', '02.2.02.01'].sort( new VersionComparator() ) == ['02.2.02.01', '02.2.02.02', '02.2.03.01']
assert ['4', '2'].sort( new VersionComparator() ) == ['2', '4']
assert ['4.1', '4'].sort( new VersionComparator() ) == ['4', '4.1']
assert ['4.1', '5'].sort( new VersionComparator() ) == ['4.1', '5']

assert new VersionComparator().compare( '1.13.4', '1.4.5' ) > 0
assert new VersionComparator().compare( '1.4.5', '1.13.4' ) < 0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

```
String maxVersion(versions) {
    versions.max { a, b ->
        List verA = a.tokenize('.')
        List verB = b.tokenize('.')
        def commonIndices = Math.min(verA.size(), verB.size())
        for (int i = 0; i < commonIndices; ++i) {
            def numA = verA[i].toInteger()
            def numB = verB[i].toInteger()
            if (numA != numB) {
                return numA <=> numB
            }
        }
        verA.size() <=> verB.size()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a modification of Tim's answer which takes two version strings and returns a boolean (true if the first is newer than the second)

```
String v1 = '02.2.01.02'
String v2 = '02.2.06.02'

boolean isMoreRecent( String a, String b ) {
    [a,b]*.tokenize('.')*.collect { it as int }.with { u, v ->
       Integer result = [u,v].transpose().findResult{ x,y -> x <=> y ?: null } ?: u.size() <=> v.size()
       return (result == 1)
    } 
}

assert !isMoreRecent(v1,v2)
assert isMoreRecent(v2,v1)​
```

Answer (score 3):

The code I am using with Jenkins ExtendedChoiceParameter (tolerant to non-integer fragments in the version string)

```
def vers = ['none']
new File(this.getBinding().getVariable('dir')).eachDir() { dir -> dirs.add(dir.getName()) }

vers.sort{x, y ->
  def xa = x.tokenize('._-'); def ya = y.tokenize('._-')
  def sz = Math.min(xa.size(), ya.size())
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    def xs = xa[i]; def ys = ya[i];
    if (xs.isInteger() && ys.isInteger()) {
      def xn = xs.toInteger()
      def yn = ys.toInteger()
      if (xn != yn) { return xn <=> yn }
    } else if (xs != ys) {
      return xs <=> ys
    }
  }

  return xa.size() <=> ya.size()
}.reverse().join(',')
```

Comment: If you're using Jenkins, you can use the compareVersions step included in the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin, which should be default in any install. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#compareversions-compare-two-version-number-strings

Answer (score 2):

Here my solution:

```
def availVersion = "1.5.0.2"
def ownVersion   = "2.6.0.1"

def availTokens = availVersion.split('\\.')
def ownTokens   = ownVersion.split('\\.')

def availSize   = availTokens.size()
def ownSize     = ownTokens.size()

def maxSize     = Math.max(availSize, ownSize)

for (int i = 1; i <= maxSize; i++) {
    def availItem = ((i <= availSize) ? availTokens[i - 1] : 0)
    def ownItem    = ((i <= ownSize)  ? ownTokens[i - 1]   : 0)

    print "Avail: ${availItem} -> Own: ${ownItem}\n"

    if ((ownItem > availItem) || ( (i == maxSize) && (ownItem >= availItem) )) {
        print "Upgrade NOT needed.\n"
        return
    }
}

print "Upgrade needed!\n"
```

Comment: There is a bug in example case availVersion = "1.5.1" and ownVersion = "1.4.5" you will always get "Upgrade NOT needed" but it should pass.

Answer (score 1):

I use gradle 4.1 in Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7. There is VersionNumber.java (under C:\Users\ssfang.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\src\core\org\gradle\util)

For example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

try{ // undocumented
    println "${android.plugin.getSdkFolder().getAbsolutePath()}"
    // Since 1.3.1 or 1.5.0? android studio version or android gradle plugin?
    println "${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}"
}catch (ignored){
}

// As of android gradle plugin v2.1.2
println android.sdkDirectory.path
println android.ndkDirectory.path
def buildToolsVer = new File(android.sdkDirectory.path, 'build-tools').listFiles().collect{ VersionNumber.parse(it.getName()) }.sort()
println buildToolsVer
printf('%s, %s\n',  buildToolsVer.head(), buildToolsVer.last().toString())

def String mostRecentVersion(List<String> versions) {
//   TreeMap<VersionNumber, String> verNum2StrMap = versions.collectEntries(new TreeMap(), { [VersionNumber.parse(it), it] })

//    TreeMap<VersionNumber, String> verNum2StrMap = versions.inject(new TreeMap()) { memo, entry ->
//        memo[VersionNumber.parse(entry)] = entry
//        memo
//    }

    TreeMap<VersionNumber, String> verNum2StrMap = versions.inject(new TreeMap()) { map, verStr ->
        map << [(VersionNumber.parse(verStr)): verStr]
    }

    // println verNum2StrMap.lastEntry().value
    verNum2StrMap.lastEntry().value
}

assert mostRecentVersion(['02.2.02.01', '02.2.02.02', '02.2.03.01']) == '02.2.03.01'
assert mostRecentVersion(['4', '2']) == '4'
assert mostRecentVersion(['4.1', '4']) == '4.1'
assert mostRecentVersion(['4.1', '5']) == '5'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ss.xsigner"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "xsigner")
    }
}
```

--

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified version of Nikita's contribution:

```
List versions = [ '02.2.02.01', '02.2.02.02', '02.2.03.01']
String mostRecentVersion = versions.sort {a, b ->
  def a1 = a.tokenize('.')*.toInteger(), b1 = b.tokenize('.')*.toInteger()   

  for (i in 0..<[a1.size(), b1.size()].min()){      
    if (a1[i] != b1[i]) {
      return a1[i] <=> b1[i]   
    }
  }
}[-1]

assert mostRecentVersion == '02.2.03.01'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to implement `Comparable` or `Comparator` interface here's the shortest solution I came up with based on the other answers:

```
    [first, second]*.tokenize('.').with { a, b ->
        [a, b].transpose().findResult { x, y -> x <=> y ?: null } ?: a.size() <=> b.size()
    }
```