# Jenkins groovy pipeline find value

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need something like this [compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723322/compare-version-strings-in-groovy)
for Jenkins pipeline

Let's imagine. I have a `value` = "6.200.01" and array `versions` looks like this

```
[Pipeline] echo
[6.000.02, 6.000.10, 6.000.12, 6.000.15, 6.000.20, 6.000.25, 6.200.00, 6.300.00]
```

( if  `value`= 6.200.01 (doesn't exist), then 6.200.00 must be picked up(the highest version lower than `value`) if  `value` is equal to any values in ver_list, then that value is picked up.

Any suggestions on a good method to do this? I am new in GROOVY

Comment: It appears that your question is the same as the link you provided. Maybe it would be helpful to explain why that solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: this solution is not OK for me, cause I need to serch and compare not just pick up the max value in the list

Comment: Have you written any code to try to solve this?