# Groovy dictionary map - how to sort according to a map's key's value - if the value is in x.x.x.x format - numberically sort version value with . char

Tags: arrays, sorting, dictionary, groovy, version

I have the following dictionary aka MAP in Groovy.

```
list = [
   [ 
     name:ProductA-manifest-file.json, 
     path:ProductA, 
     properties: [
                   [
                     key:release, 
                     value:RC1.0
                   ], 
                   [ key:PIPELINE_VERSION, 
                     value:1.0.0.11
                   ]
                ], 
    repo:some-generic-repo-local, 
   ],
   [ 
     name:ProductA-manifest-file.json, 
     path:ProductA, 
     properties: [
                   [
                     key:release, 
                     value:RC1.0
                   ], 
                   [ key:PIPELINE_VERSION, 
                     value:1.0.0.75
                   ]
                ], 
    repo:some-generic-repo-local, 
   ],
   [ 
     name:ProductA-manifest-file.json, 
     path:ProductA, 
     properties: [
                   [
                     key:release, 
                     value:RC1.0
                   ], 
                   [ key:PIPELINE_VERSION, 
                     value:1.0.0.1104
                   ]
                ], 
    repo:some-generic-repo-local, 
   ],
   [
    more similar entries here containing 
   ],
   [
    more similar entries here
   ]
]
```

I'm trying to sort this map acc. to **properties's key = PIPELINE_VERSION's value** which is in the format of ***x.x.x.x*** i.e. **4 digit set** case.

I tried the following command but it's not giving me the entry which contains 1.0.0.1104 as PIPELINE_VERSION. It's giving me 1.0.0.75 (which seems like some kind of string type sort.

```
// Sort the list entries acc. to pipeline version
def sortedList = list.sort { it.properties.PIPELINE_VERSION.value }
println "###### sortedList" + sortedList
println "\n^^^^\n"
println sortedList.last()  // this should return me the entry which contains 1.0.0.1104 but I'm getting 1.0.0.75
 }
```

Also tried using **.toInteger()** as `def sortedList = list.sort { it.properties.PIPELINE_VERSION.toInteger().value }` but that didn't work giving an error.

```
17:07:22 Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.toInteger() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
17:07:22 Possible solutions: toUnique(), toUnique()
17:07:22 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.toInteger() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
17:07:22 Possible solutions: toUnique(), toUnique()
```

Tried:`list.sort {it.value.tokenize('.').last()}` that didn't do either.

Smaller example will be:

```
map = ['a':'1.0.0.11', d:'1.0.0.85', 'b':'1.0.0.1104', 'c':"1.0.0.75"]

println " before sorting : " + map

//map = map.sort {it.value }   // this doesn't work if the value is not a pure number format aka x.x.x. format ok lets try the following    
map = map.sort {it.value.tokenize('.').last()} // cool that didn't work either

println " after  sorting : " + map
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I get the entry which has the highest PIPELINE_VERSION value?
2. How can I get the Nth array index entry which contains the highest PIPELINE_VERSOIN in its value.
3. How to handle N no. of digit set set cases? i.e. 1.0.0 or 1.2 or 1.0.0.12 or 1.4.1.9.255

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723322/compare-version-strings-in-groovy

Comment: :) pretty much but not exact as that didn't deal with the same structure and the solution looks pretty lengthy. The one dmahapatro mentioned below, looks cleaner but I tried to make it more cleaner (one-liner) in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, not close enough for closing  hopefully it helps with the version comparing though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work (assuming the format X.X.X.X always has X as a number)

```
def sortClosure = { a, b ->

  // Extract the pattern
  def extract = { 
    it.properties.find { it.key == 'PIPELINE_VERSION' }?.value?.tokenize(/./) 
  }

  // Transpose the numbers to compare
  // gives [[1,1], [0,0], [0,0], [11, 1104]] for example
  def transposed = [extract(a), extract(b)].transpose()

  // Then compare the first occurrence of non-zero value (-1 or 1)
  def compareInt = transposed.collect { 
    it[0].toInteger() <=> it[1].toInteger() 
  }.find()

  compareInt ?: 0
}

list.sort(sortClosure)
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. I'm accepting this as an answer even though I used your hint to make it into a one-liner.

Comment: can you explain what's that `?` characters in that line. Also, if somehow we can get the highest PIPELINE_VERSION covering all 4 or N. no. of digit sets. Right now, it's looking only for the 4th digit set.

Comment: This is actually the best solution as it covers all cases i.e. it'll cover all N digit sets in PIPELINE_VERSION

Comment: One finding: It would be better to use this line instead of the one above.
`transposed.collect { it[0].toInteger() <=> it[1].toInteger() }.find() ?: 0`

Comment: yes that makes sense as well. This will avoid a getAt() operation on a empty list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def versions = ['a':'1.0.0.11', d:'1.0.0.85', 'b':'1.0.0.1104', 'c':"1.0.0.75"]
//sort:
def sorted = versions.sort{ (it.value=~/\d+|\D+/).findAll() }
```

result:

```
[a:1.0.0.11, c:1.0.0.75, d:1.0.0.85, b:1.0.0.1104]
```

Comment: `def sorted = versions.sort {it.value.tokenize('.').last().toInteger() }` is more cleaner. In my nest original map, it's a MAP containing an array as properties's value, containing arrays of dictionary/maps. Trying to get that working now.

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner solution worked.

For the smaller example!

```
def versions = ['a':'1.0.0.11', d:'1.0.0.85', 'b':'1.0.0.1104', 'c':"1.0.0.75"]
map = map.sort {it.value.tokenize('.').last().toInteger() }
```

OK, found the ***shenzi***(one-liner) solution for the complex structure (hint from dmahapatro's answer):
i.e. a map > containing array > containing another map for PIPELINE_VERSION.

```
println "\n\n before sorting : " + list

list = list.sort {it.properties.find { it.key == 'PIPELINE_VERSION' }?.value?.tokenize('.').last().toInteger() }

println " after  sorting : " + list
println "\n\n The last entry which contains the sorted shenzi is: " + map.last()
```

NOTE: The above solution and other answers so far, will only if the PIPELINE first 3 digit sets are 1.0.0 i.e. it's only deciding the highest number based on the 4th digit set (.last()). It'd be fun to use a similar one-liner to find highest PIPELINE_VERSION which actually covers all 4 or N no. of digit sets.

Comment: NOTE: It's better to use `.toLong()` than using `.toInteger()`

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
def map = ['a':'1.0.0.11', d:'1.0.0.85', 'b':'1.0.0.1104', 'c':"1.0.0.75"]

map = map.sort { a, b ->
    compareVersion(a.value, b.value)
}
```

the goal becomes to write a `compareVersion` function that satisfies these (incomplete) tests:

```
assert 0  == compareVersion('1.0.0.0', '1.0.0.0')
assert 1  == compareVersion('1.1.0.0', '1.0.0.0')
assert -1 == compareVersion('1.1.0.0', '1.2.0.0')
assert 1  == compareVersion('1.1.3.0', '1.1.2.0')
assert 1  == compareVersion('1.1.4.1104', '1.1.4.11')
```

Here is one implementation. It's not the shortest but is quite "Groovy" in style:

```
//
// e.g. a = '1.0.0.11', b = '1.0.0.85'
//
def compareVersion = { a, b ->
    // e.g. [1, 0, 0, 11]
    def listA = a.tokenize('.').collect { it as int }

    // e.g. [1, 0, 0, 85]
    def listB = b.tokenize('.').collect { it as int }

    // e.g. [0, 0, 0, -1]
    def compareList = [listA, listB].transpose().collect { it[0] <=> it[1] }

    // return first non-zero value in compareList, or 0 if there are none
    compareList.inject(0) { result, item ->
        (result) ?: item
    }
}
```

Output of the original map, and sorted:

```
$ groovy Q.groovy 
 before sorting : [a:1.0.0.11, d:1.0.0.85, b:1.0.0.1104, c:1.0.0.75]
 after  sorting : [a:1.0.0.11, c:1.0.0.75, d:1.0.0.85, b:1.0.0.1104]
```