# Most concise way of comparing versions in Java

Tags: java, groovy

Let's say I have a version of the form of `major.minor.patch`, e.g. `1.2.3`, and I want to compare it to another version `1.1.5`, as `2 > 1` the first version is greater than the second. How can I write the most concise & efficient compare function for the `class Version`:

```java
class Version implements Comparable<Version> {

    int major
    int minor
    int patch

    @Override
    int compareTo(Version otherVersion) {
        // ... TODO
    }
}
```

Answers can be in `Java` or `Groovy`.

Comment: "*as 1 > 2 the first version is greater than the second*" seems unusual. Lets clarify it: if you have versions like `1.1.0` `1.2.1` `2.1.1` how should they be ordered?

Comment: @Pshemo `1.2.3` > `1.1.5` - comparing the "minor" field stops the comparison (OP's phrasing is a bit rough).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch True, I realize that "first" refers to `1.2.3` while "second" to `1.1.5` and "first version is greater than the second" confirms `1.2.3 > 1.1.5` but still that `1>2` is bugging me :)

Comment: Sorry typo haha.

Comment: *Concise* and *efficient* are competing goals. Which do you want most?

Comment: Not always, let's see, maybe I should ask this as well with a version of the form 1.2.3.4...{N} where efficiency would matter more then. But I would like to see some nice looking short code, who wouldn't!?

Comment: for groovy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59939846/1276664 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/7737400/1276664

Comment: Those answers are not concise at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groovy variant

```
@groovy.transform.ToString
class Version implements Comparable<Version> {

    int major
    int minor
    int patch

    @Override
    int compareTo(Version other) {
        major<=>other.major ?: minor<=>other.minor ?: patch<=>other.patch
    }
}

def v0=new Version(major:1,minor:2,patch:11)
def v1=new Version(major:1,minor:2,patch:22)
def v2=new Version(major:1,minor:2,patch:33)

assert v1.compareTo(v0)==1
assert v1.compareTo(v2)==-1
assert v1.compareTo(v1)==0
```

Comment: Yes I was trying to get this `<=>` guy working! I was trying all sorts of `major<=>other.major | minor<=>other.minor | patch<=>other.patch` stuff with different operators. I really like this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest adding getters for your three fields, then a `Comparator` using chained *comparing* functions. Like,

```
public int getMajor() {
    return major;
}

public int getMinor() {
    return minor;
}

public int getPatch() {
    return patch;
}

private static final Comparator<Version> COMP = Comparator
        .comparingInt(Version::getMajor)
        .thenComparingInt(Version::getMinor)
        .thenComparingInt(Version::getPatch);

@Override
public int compareTo(Version otherVersion) {
    return COMP.compare(this, otherVersion);
}
```

Comment: We can also make `Comparator<Version> comp` `static` so that one instance would be shared between all instances of `Version` class.

Comment: Another possible improvement would be using `comparingInt` and `thenComparingInt` vs `comparing` and `thenComparing` since getters return `int` to avoid boxing/ungoxing (although I am not sure if it will save us a lot of time/space since JIT may notice what is going on here and optimize it).

Comment: @Pshemo Two for two, nice.