# Comparing library version strings in Groovy

Tags: groovy, string-comparison

Let's say I have a following list of library's versions:

`List myList = ["4.11", "4.12", "4.13", "5.1"]`

I need to check if the first element of the list is equal to or greater than "4.11".

I do it this way:

```
#compateTo() returns 0 if the caller string equals to the argument string
#compateTo() returns > 0 if the caller string is greater than the argument string

if (myList[0].compareTo("4.11") >= 0) {
    println("equal or greater than 4.11")
} else {
    println("less than 4.11")
}
```

However, let's consider this case:
`List myList = ["4.9"]`

Comparing two strings character by character it gets to `9` compared to `1` and since 9 is greater than 1 it returns `equal or greater than 4.11`, which is incorrect.

What would be the best way to fix it? I considered this:

```
def strToDecimal = Double.parseDouble(myList[0])
```

to get a decimal number and compare two decimal numbers 4.9 and 4.11 but the problem is the same.

I cannot use anything that would require an import statement.

Comment: Convert each number to an int and compare them. If you don't want that then compare by string length first (smaller length is smaller), for same length compare char by char.

Comment: @OnnoRouast I updated my example in the end of description with a double conversion. But how to I compare two doubles? Not char by char but based on their value. Is there such a Groovy method?

Comment: It is not clear from the description that you're probably comparing versions of libraries. I think there is not other way than to write your own code that would split the version  by "." and compare the digits individually. Here is the ready code in Java: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-two-version-numbers/ You may use it in your Groovy script. The funny thing will start if you have not only digits, but something like 4.10-RC. Hopefully your versions are always real releases.

Comment: Also look here, there are a lot of different ideas on how to solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723322/compare-version-strings-in-groovy

Comment: " cannot use anything that would require an import statement." - That is a very peculiar requirement.  Import statements are only there to help the compiler, identify which class you intend to reference.  I think you will get the exact same bytecode if you eliminate import statements and use fully qualified class names.

Comment: @AndrejIstomin Thnaks a lot! It's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java >= 9, I'd go with the [Version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Version.html) class:

```
// List myList = ["4.11", "4.12", "4.13", "5.1"]
List myList = ["4.9"]
if (java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.Version.parse(myList[0]).compareTo(java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.Version.parse("4.11")) >= 0) {
    println("equal or greater than 4.11")
} else {
    println("less than 4.11")
}
```

If your Java version is <= 9, then you may checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723322/compare-version-strings-in-groovy). There are some ideas on how to solve your problem.