# Groovy: How to sort String array of dot-separated digits

Tags: arrays, sorting, groovy

Consider an array:

```
def arr= [
    "7.11.2",
    "6.2.1",
    "1.4",
    "4.13.5",
    "4.2.5",
    "13",
    "1.2.5",
    "1.4.2",
    "6.15.3",
    "6.4.4"
]
```

I need it to look like this:

```
def list = [
    "1.2.5",
    "1.4",
    "1.4.2",
    "4.2.5",
    "4.13.5",
    "6.2.1",
    "6.4.4",
    "6.15.3",
    "7.11.2",
    "13"
]
```

Please advise how to do it.

Calling `.sort()` on an array seems to sort it digit by digit rather than by numbers separated by dots.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936014/sort-list-of-version-numbers-groovy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse and numberize your versions like so:

```
def arr= [
    "7.11.2",
    "6.2.1",
    "1.4",
    "4.13.5",
    "4.2.5",
    "13",
    "1.2.5",
    "1.4.2",
    "6.15.3",
    "6.4.4"
]

def sorted = arr.sort{ 
    def nums = it.split( /\./ )*.toInteger()
    while( 3 > nums.size() ) nums << 0
    int accum = 0
    nums.reverse().eachWithIndex{ num, ix -> accum += num * Math.pow( 10, ix * 2 ) }
    accum
}

assert sorted == [
  "1.2.5",
  "1.4",
  "1.4.2",
  "4.2.5",
  "4.13.5",
  "6.2.1",
  "6.4.4",
  "6.15.3",
  "7.11.2",
  "13"
]
```

Comment: You can replace the three last lines in the sort closure with `nums.inject(0) { a, n -> a*100 + n }` to be a tad more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Although I totally agree with the previous answer, I'd like to mention another option. If you're using Java 9+, there is a class called [java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.Version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Version.html) Maybe for your example it is an overkill, but if you have more complex versions like `-alpha`, `-RC` etc. This class can be very helpful. You just need to use `Version.compareTo`method for sorting.