# In Groovy -How to compare versions for major.minor.patch and major minor?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have two versions verA=1.9.1 and VerB=1.12 when i am comparing it with math.min and with size but its not doing correct comparison.

```
verA=1.9.1
verB=1.12

List verA = a.tokenize('.')
List verB = b.tokenize('.')
     
def commonIndices = Math.min(verA.size(), verB.size())
    
for (int i = 0; i < commonIndices; ++i) {
  def numA = verA[i].toInteger()
  def numB = verB[i].toInteger()
  
  if (numA > numB) {
    echo "$verA is greater than $verB"
    }
```

```
But it is not going in the if condition because its comparing the major and minor version not the patch version.
it works fine if i provide both the versions like this verA=1.12 and verB=1.11
```

i have checked this [Compare version strings in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723322/compare-version-strings-in-groovy) but this is working for version compared against same decimal digits. example, verA= major.minor.patch verB=major.minor.patch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgroovy%5D+compare+versions

Comment: The duplicate answers work with versions with different digit groups (see the test code in them)