# Groovy how to compare two floats

Tags: groovy

I need to check an array and get all the values if the os value is above 13.0 . So my script is like :

```
for(String item: jsonObj.devices) {
    if (item.os >= 13.0) {
        name = item.name
        os = item.os
        println name
        println os
    }
}
```

But it's not listing any values. The `item.os have values like : 9, 14.5.6, 13.0.1, 12.1`

Could you please let me know where I am wrong here.

Comment: is `item.os` a String? Also, where is `echo` coming from?

Comment: no, its a number.

Comment: `14.5.6` could not be a number because there are two dots

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723322/compare-version-strings-in-groovy