# how to check jre version using java application

Tags: compatibility, java

i have made an application in JDK7, but the jre6 is still using in the market, and if i send my jar file to someone with jre6, it wont work, is there a way that application checks the jre version and if it doesn't compat then ask user to update..

Comment: Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java) how to compare the JRE version.

Comment: @Crazenezz: is there a way by  checking thru dos, by creating a windows batch file and virtual basic, could this be done?? if it match then it'll execute the jar?? can this be practically done wt i am saying??

Comment: There is a possibility to do that in batch. You can convert the algorithm in the link that I give above and translate it with batch programming style (If you feel comfortable using that).

Answer (score 12):

You can use [System.getProperty(String key);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) method with `"java.version"` as key.

```
String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
```

Example output:

```
1.6.0_30
```

The available keys can find at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: will that work if jre is mismatching...cause in my case the jre file just gives the splash screen and closes itself if i use jre6.. i need some fool proof solution!!

Comment: its not showing any exception...the program wont run...i had made an exception error dialog box.....but nothing works..

Answer (score 2):

```
System.getProperty("java.version")
```

- [Demo](http://ideone.com/lDR83)

**Note**: It will return current jvm's version, jvm on which this code is executing, If you have java6 & java7 installed on your computer and you are running this code on java 7 it will show you version 7

Comment: will that work if jre is mismatching...cause in my case the jre file just gives the splash screen and closes itself if i use jre6.. i need some fool proof solution!!

Comment: its not giving any exception....its just not running...i have made a error dialog in case of any exception....so i havent  shown anything....

Answer (score 2):

```
static public void main(String[] arg) throws IOException
    {
        PrintStream out = System.out;
        Properties pro = System.getProperties();
        Set set = pro.entrySet();

       Iterator<Map.Entry<String , String >> itr = set.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry ent = itr.next();
            out.println(ent.getKey() + " -> " + ent.getValue() + "\n");
        }
}
```

Use `System.getProperty("java.version")` or `System.getProperty("java.runtime.version")` to get installed version of java.
The above code snipped helps you find out more details such as java vendor name , OS etc.

Answer (score 0):

here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/CheckVersion.htm) that checks the version and trows an exception if the version is incorrect using `System.getProperty("java.version");`

Comment: will that work if jre is mismatching...cause in my case the jre file just gives the splash screen and closes itself if i use jre6.. i need some fool proof solution!!

Comment: I cant verify it atm but if you put this in a class that gets loaded before any jre7 specific classes are loaded it should work

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Web Start you have a messagebox about the java version if it is not compatible with your jar. For example:

```
<resources>
       <j2se version="1.4+"
             href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
```

in the jnlp file

Answer (score 0):

UnsupportedClassVersionError would occur if you try to run a Java file on an older version of jre compared to the version on which it was compiled.

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
[at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)] 
on running a compiled java class file.

In essence you can not run .class files that are compiled with a newer version than the JVM.