# How to parse the version name to integer in android to validate?

Tags: java, android

I want to validate the version.I am using this code

```
String deviceVersion= Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
String limitVersion="4.0";
```

storing it in a variable For eg:deviceVersion  is 2.3.6 i cannot convert it to the integer .How can i do this.

I want to check like this.

```
if(deviceVersion => limitVersion )
{
//do something
}else{
//do something
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the API level. This is one of the very first thing the [Android Developer's site](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html) teaches you in their training docs, if you haven't had a chance to read it yet I highly recommend it. There's a ton of good information in there.

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
    // Is Honeycomb or newer
}
```

Comment: not worked for me as expected, for version R, it shows 'Base11 | Donut | Froyo | JellyBean' instead of R

Answer (score 3):

You can get SDK version as integer by

```
int version=Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

then you can compare it to some value. Like

```
if(version>=Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1){
    do_something();
}
else{
    do_something_else();
}
```

You can get other version code by

```
Build.VERSION_CODES.*
```

Eclipse IDE will help you to find what you are looking for.

Edit: Fixed for the version ID you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

This will basically take the first integer before the first dot. Make sure to do appropriate checks if the script is empty or if a dot even exists first.

```
String versionInt = deviceVersion.split("\\.")[0];
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I know that Android provides a native way of getting the version code, but since that solution was answered in a few answers already - I decided to provide a different perspective - of using native Java functionality. Maybe that's what the OP needed. Who said he needed to get the Android build version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
android.os.Build.VERSION
```

to get the version, and then you can use it to implement your code..