# How to compare java versions?

Tags: java, spring, java-8

This code used to work fine with java 6 and 7, but running it with a jre 1.8 method getMajorJavaVersion returns 2. Is it a bug, or are we doing something wrong?

```
public static void validateJavaVersion() {
    // check whether the current JVM version is at least Java 6
    if (JdkVersion.getMajorJavaVersion() < JdkVersion.JAVA_16) {
        throw new APIException("OpenMRS requires Java 6, but is running under " + JdkVersion.getJavaVersion());
    }
}
```

getJavaVersion gives the version as 1.8.0_20

Note that JdkVersion belongs to Spring, not to the JRE itself.

Another question: is there any API to compare two java versions? Preferably native but we can use Apache commons and Spring too.

Comment: Is this the Spring JdkVersion class? You should include that in your tags - it's an important piece of context. I'm just guessing from having done some searches.

Comment: You're right, it's the Spring one. I assumed it was part of the java api.

Comment: JAVA_18 should be 5. Are you **sure** you're using that JDK?

Comment: I'm sure because getJavaVersion returns  1.8.0_20 and 
getMajorJavaVersion 2

Comment: Getting version of java is part of the problem, but comparing two  versions as strings is not trivial.

Comment: This question solves my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java