# How do I compare two numeric string in Java?

Tags: java, string-comparison

I would like to compare two numeric string such as "1.0.1" and "2.1.1".
May I know that is there any string utility method in Java to compare or need to implement like remove .(dot), parse to integer and compare manually? Thank you.

Comment: How will you parse "1.0.1" as a number? its got 2 decimal points...

Comment: @Bus Car,  As per I know there is no single utility method to solve you purpose. You need to implement as you told.

Comment: Looks like duplicate for Version Comparision: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java)

Comment: @BusCar - Whichever answer has helped you, kindly upvote and accept the answer. It is a very bad habit to leave the question marked as unresolved. Else, from the next time experts would prevent answering your question! Good Luck, :)

Answer (score 0):

> remove .(dot)

```
myString.replaceAll("\\.","")
```

> parse to integer

```
int myInt = Integer.parseInt(myString);
```

> compare manually

```
if(myInt < myInt2) { // ....
```

Comment: Please correct `Integer.parse` by `Integer.parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to replace all the dots with an empty string.

```
String str1 = "1.0.1";
str1 = str1.replaceAll(".","");
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
// similarly for num2
String str2 = "2.1.2";
str2 = str2.replaceAll(".","");
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
if (num1 == num2)
// do Something
else
// do Something else.
```

Comment: remember that strings are immutable in Java so the String.replace() method will return the new string, not just simplify modify the original. try: str1 = str1.replaceAll(".",""); and the same for str2

Comment: @Dave - Oh, Thanks. I forget assigning the new string to original string reference. I was doing 2 works at the same time, :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mystr.replace('.', '')` and compare using `mystr.equals(mystr2)`. Or to compare the strings as number you could parse to Integer, like so:

```
myInt = Integer.parseInt(mystr);
if(myInt == myInt2) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the strings on the dot (`string.split("\\.")` — you have to escape the `.` since `split` takes a regex, and you have to escape the escape because you're typing it as a Java string literal), and then parse and compare each component from the two strings. As you do so, if the components are unequal, there's your answer; otherwise, go on to the next one. If there isn't a next one, the two strings are equal.

For instance, given "1.2.3" and "1.4.5", the splits would be ["1", "2", "3"] and ["1", "4", "5"]. So you'd first parse and compare the strings at index 0; they're both 1, so you go to the next index. Then you parse and compare the strings at index 1; 2 < 3, so "1.2.3" < "1.4.5".

Depending on your use case, you may also need to cover use cases like if they have different number of components (for instance, "1.2.3" vs "1.2").

Do *not* just remove the dot, as other answers have said, unless you want 2.3.4 to be lower than 1.23.4, since 234 < 1234.