# How can i compare the value of a string response against version of installed app

Tags: java, token, tokenize, string-parsing, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to write a auto update using Volley library and Dropbox API. I've set it up so that it reads a blog page and finds this chunk of code:

```
if (response != null) {
            boolean resp = response.contains("<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-6791062644900393367' itemprop='description articleBody'>\n" +
                    "1.1.8\n" +
                    "<div style='clear: both;'></div>");
```

Using this code I can say *if response is less than 1.1.8 then download the update*. I tried to do so using this approach:

```
  if (!resp){My Intent code is here }
```

but with this code it downloads the update even if the version is up to date.

I've now added the code below to capture the version number. but I cant seam to get my head round how to compare that against either my version in my gradle and to say *if less than please update*.

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-6791062644900393367' itemprop='description articleBody'>\n" +
            "([0-9.]+)\n" +
            "<div style='clear: both;'></div>");

Matcher m = p.matcher(response);
 if (m.find()) {
String version = m.group();
// more code here
```

}

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to add more code? I've read I can't use less than it. In this way I have also tried using "**<=**" comparison. If you think it may be some other piece of my code causing the problem let me know and I can post more for you to see.

Comment: I edited my answer including the full working code that you can simply copy and paste to be ready to go on. Check it out, bro'! I hope that it'll be the accepted answer you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokeinze that string usin `\n` as a delimiter, isolate the middle token (either by index - 2nd aka 1 - or by parsing tokens with a simple regex).
Use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) class.

**--EDIT: Here's the full example--**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String response = "blahblah<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-6791062644900393367' itemprop='description articleBody'>\n"
            + "1.1.8"//try "1.1.7", "1.1.9", etc to see that this does work
            + "\n<div style='clear: both;'></div>yaddayadda";//this is just to setup the test: you're obviously getting response from somewhere
    String myVersion = "1.1.8";
    System.out.println("My version: "+myVersion);
    Integer versionOK = isVersionOK(response, myVersion);
    String s;
    if (versionOK != null)
    {
        switch (versionOK)
        {
            case 0:
                s = "equal";
                break;
            case -1:
                s = "greater";
                break;
            default:
                s = "lesser";
        }
        System.out.println("Version is " + s);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Couldn't detect version!");
}

/**
 *
 * @param response
 * @return 0 if equal, -1 if greater, 1 if lesser, null if not found or
 * anything goes unexpectedly-
 */
static Integer isVersionOK(String response, String myVersion)
{
    String whatToSearchForBefore = "<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-6791062644900393367' itemprop='description articleBody'>\n";
    String whatToSearchForAfter = "\n<div style='clear: both;'></div>";
    if (response != null)
    {
        boolean resp = response.contains(whatToSearchForBefore)&&response.contains(whatToSearchForAfter);
        System.out.println("response does " + (resp ? "" : "not ") + "contain the version number");
        if (resp)
        {
            String whatWeFound = response.substring(response.indexOf(whatToSearchForBefore), response.indexOf(whatToSearchForAfter) + whatToSearchForAfter.length());
            System.out.println("----\n"+whatWeFound+"\n----");
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(whatWeFound, "\n");
            st.nextToken();
            String version = st.nextToken();
            System.out.println("Version: " + version);
            return myVersion.compareToIgnoreCase(version);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: If you hold on, I will write the actual code for you in late [italian] afternoon (i.e. in a couple houra)

Comment: im just going to try this now will report back thanks @unai

Answer (score 2):

Capture the version number using a regular expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-6791062644900393367' itemprop='description articleBody'>\n" +
                "([0-9.]+)\n" +
                "<div style='clear: both;'></div>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(response);
if (m.find()) {
    String version = m.group();
    // more code here
}
```

where `([0-9.]+)` captures any combination of digits (`0-9`) and periods (`.`).

Now you just need to figure out how to check if `version` is less than `1.1.8`. You can't use string comparison for this, since `"1.1.10"` compares less than `"1.1.8"`, even though it's a higher "version".
See [How do you compare two version Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/198431/5221149)

Comment: would the string comparison go here ----> //more code here

Comment: @MarkHarrop Yes, except using a *version* comparison, not a plain string comparison.