# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float:

Tags: android, android-studio, exception

I got the application of version 1.1.2 in the playstore. I am checking the update of the playstore in the application but I got the error. I researched but couldnot get any solution. I got stuck with the error NumberFormatException.I have implemented as follows:

```
 try {
        currentVersion = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have tried to fetch the version number of the application from playstore.

```
private class GetVersionCode extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String newVersion = null;

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+context.getPackageName()+"&hl=en" )
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get();
            if (document != null) {
                Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
                for (Element ele : element) {
                    if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                        Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                        for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                            newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newVersion;

    }


    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(String onlineVersion) {

        super.onPostExecute(onlineVersion);

        if (onlineVersion != null && !onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {

            if (Float.valueOf(currentVersion) < Float.valueOf(onlineVersion)) {
                //show anything
            }

        }

        Log.d("update", "Current version " + currentVersion + "playstore version " + onlineVersion);

    }
}
```

Comment: What type is your `currentVersion` field?

Comment: You should use versionCode instead of versionName. versionName is a string, versionCode is an integer.

Comment: how to solve it please explain @AlexShevelev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentVersion` and `onlineVersion` both are of type `String`. `1.1.2` is a `String` and not a number.

Instead of comparing them as Floats (which doesn't work as they are Strings):

```
if (Float.valueOf(currentVersion) < Float.valueOf(onlineVersion)) {
   //show anything
}
```

You should compare them as Strings to check if the versions are different:

```
if (!onlineVersion.equals(currentVersion)) {
   //show anything
}
```

If you want to compare if the `onlineVerson` is newer (instead of just different) you should take a look at that solution: [How do you compare two version Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java)

The preferred way of comparing Android app versions would of course be through the `versionCode` because it is of type `int` and needs to increase with every new version. `versionName` can be an arbitrary value and nothing keeps you from naming the first version `1.0` and the following versions `0.8` or `Mountain Lion`, making them hard to compare.

A better solution might be to store the most recent `versionCode` on a webserver and check for this code instead of going to the Play Store and parsing the store listing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use..

```
.versionCode // this will return integer
```

`.versionName` will return string version name. while `versionCode` will return integer.

**But as per your code and functionality... you have to use the version name in floating like String(eg:- 1.1 or 1.2 etc).** then you can use version name also.

Comment: what should I do then? can you please explain.