# How to compare version numbers in form of string delimited by '.'?

Tags: hive

I have data like below. I need to compare the numbers in each field and rank the numbers by date and versions. I have tried explode and split but only the first field (10, 11, 10) are returning.

```
2018-07-01 10.1.1
2018-07-01 11.1.1
2018-08-02 10.0.5
```

Comment: A straightforward implementation is comparing the first major version, if they're equal then compare the next minors until you either reach a resolution or total equality.

Comment: How would I go about comparing each field? The versions are stored as strings.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java

Comment: Well... I don't really know which programming language you're using, but basically the two concepts are exploding/splitting strings and parsing strings as integers.

Comment: Sorry. I'm doing this in Hive.

Comment: While the general approach is true, I'm not sure this answer directly addresses the problem of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`split(version,'\\.')`  will return array of version numbers:

Major version number is `split(version,'\\.')[0]`

Minor version is `split(version,'\\.')[1]`

And the third number is  `split(version,'\\.')[2]`

Use `cast(string as int)` to convert them to int, like this: `cast(split(version,'\\.')[0] as int)`

Compare them one by one.

Comment: So the versions are in string format right now. Do I convert the string to int and then do split? Or split and then cast to int?

Comment: @HuaCha Yes, they are strings. Use `cast(split(version,'\\.')[0] as int)` to convert to int