# Remove duplicate entry from list with a condition in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, filter, duplicates

So, I am implementing a POM parser. I've got to the point where I can get all dependencies, but some artifacts may be duplicate with different versions. Like gradle, I want it to just fetch the greater version among those. But in kotlin, I can only see examples of removing duplicates using distinctBy function which does not accept a condition. I wanna filter it by only removing the duplicate entry which has the lowest version and keeping the greater one. How can I do so?

The entries in my list is as follows

```
data class Artifact(val groupId: String, val artifactId: String, val version: String)
```

edit: For example, let the list be like

```
Artifact("com.squareup.okio", "okio-jvm", "3.2.0")
Artifact("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8", "1.6.20")
Artifact("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-stdlib-common", "1.5.20")
Artifact("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-stdlib-common", "1.6.21")
Artifact("org.jetbrains", "annotations", "13.0")
```

And the output is expected to be like

```
Artifact("com.squareup.okio", "okio-jvm", "3.2.0")
Artifact("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8", "1.6.20")
Artifact("org.jetbrains.kotlin", "kotlin-stdlib-common", "1.6.21")
Artifact("org.jetbrains", "annotations", "13.0")
```

i.e, to remove the version that is the lowest among the duplicates

Comment: Can you give an example of such a list that you have, and the filtered list that you want?

Comment: @ArpitShukla I've added the example of a list and the expected list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main part of this is fairly straightforward: you can use [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) to group the artifacts by group ID and artifact ID, and then [`maxBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by.html)<sup>*</sup> to select the latest version from each group.

A more tricky part is comparing version strings… But [luckily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198431/how-do-you-compare-two-version-strings-in-java), the Java stdlib<sup>⁑</sup> has [a class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Version.html) for this!

So you can simply:

```
import java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.Version

data class Artifact(val groupId: String, val artifactId: String, val version: String)

fun main() {
    // Some simple sample data:
    val deps = listOf(Artifact("gp", "art", "9.2"), Artifact("gp", "art", "9.10"), Artifact("gp", "art", "10.0"), Artifact("gp2", "art2", "1.0"))

    // Find the latest version of each dependency:
    val latestDeps = deps.groupBy{ it.groupId to it.artifactId }.values
                         .map{ it.maxBy{ Version.parse(it.version) }}

    // And display the result:
    println(latestDeps)
}
```

(That creates a set. Since the items will be unique, but have no inherent ordering, it would make sense to call `toSet()` on the result… but I leave that to you!)

---

(* That's deprecated now in favour of `maxByOrNull()`, but I'm ignoring that for simplicity, as the groups here will never be empty.)

---

(⁑ If you're not running on Kotlin/JVM, then you'll have to write your own version-number-comparing function. I've written one; it's a bit fiddly, but not too hard. — I think you have to split the string on dots and then compare the individual numbers numerically, pairwise, though it's complicated if you have to handle non-numeric parts such as trailing `a` or `-SNAPSHOT` or patch numbers… If you need to do that, it would probably be best as a separate question.)